# Pattern name for create in constructor, delete in destructor (C++)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, raii

Traditionally, in C++, you would create any dependencies in the constructor and delete them in the destructor.

```
class A
{
 public:
    A() { m_b = new B(); }
    ~A() { delete m_b; }
 private:
    B* m_b;
};
```

This technique/pattern of resource acquisition, does it have a common name?
I'm quite sure I've read it somewhere but can't find it now.

Edit:
As many has pointed out, this class is incomplete and should really implement a copy constructor and assignment operator.
Originally, I intentionally left it out since it wasn't relevant to the actual question: the name of the pattern. However, for completeness and to encourage good practices, the accepted answer is what it is.

Comment: Bad class A. Copy constructor and Assignment operator are missing.

Comment: A simpler solution if copy/assignment isn't required is to derive from boost::noncopyable. Saves you having to define those two functions. (and ensures they're not accidentally called)

Comment: What a pointless usage of dynamic memory. What a terrible design and formatting of the class. What a terrible example of C++ overall. Why would you ever do that? Why would you ever use new and delete anyway, and in such a pointless way. Just do `class A{ B m_b = {}; }` and you get pretty much the same but without risky pointers and using less than 1/4th the code.

Comment: You don't need to use `private:` because the entire point of the `class` keyword is to define members private as default, as they're meant to be on top of the class, and not hidden at the bottom in a place you need to scroll down the entire page to see them. In my 30 years of programming I have never seen a single argument to put the members at the bottom and the language is clearly meant to have them at the top.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to your question is RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).

But your example is dangerous:

Solution 1 use a smart pointer:

```
class A
{
  public:
     A(): m_b(new B) {}
  private:
     boost::shared_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

Solution 2: Remember the rule of 4:
If your class contains an "Owned RAW pointer" then you need to override all the compiler generated methods.

```
class A
{
  public:
     A():              m_b(new B)           {}
     A(A const& copy): m_b(new B(copy.m_b)) {}
     A& operator=(A const& copy)
     {
         A  tmp(copy);
         swap(tmp);
         return *this;
     }
    ~A()
     {
         delete m_b;
     }
     void swap(A& dst) throw ()
     {
         using std::swap;
         swap(m_b, dst.m_b);
     }
  private:
     B* m_b;
};
```

I use the term "Owned RAW Pointer" above as it is the simplest example. But RAII is applicable to all resources and when your object contains a resource that you need to manage ('Owned RAW Poiner', DB Handle etc).

Comment: Why is his example leaky? He allocated on constructor and deallocates on destructor

Comment: Because of the compiler generated copy constructor.

Comment: "owns a raw pointer" should probably be expanded to "or a resource handle of any other kind". The same applies for file handles, sockets, database connections or any other resource whose lifetime has to be managed.

Comment: Btw, this really shows the power of "the fastest gun in the west" syndrome. This answer is by far more complete and detailed, but because the other one is at the top, it's getting all the upvotes...

Comment: RAII: "Resource **Acquisition** Is Initialization"

Comment: @jalf it may also be that the code shown is quite disgusting and something you should not do without a good explanation.

Comment: @PabloAriel `code shown is quite disgusting` In what way?

Comment: In that you're using dynamic memory for no reason, you put the most important part of the class at the bottom (the member it contains, which tells what the class is meant to manage and thus its reason to exist), in that you use a raw pointer, in that it makes an extra copy of the value of `A const &copy`, in that it uses `using` for "using" the function only once, in that it uses four lines for a one-line destructor... as I mentioned, this class can be written as `class A{ B m_b = {}; }` and it should unless there is a good explanation to do it some other way.

Comment: There is a myriad of good examples of RAII, such as lock guards, COM+ smart pointers, smart pointers in general (tho the std:: implementations are questionable at the very least), file mappings and so on. There is no reason, however, to do something like in your example, wrapping new() and delete() for no reason whatsoever. Not a real-world example and dangerous to imitate.

Comment: @PabloAriel: Thanks for the input. I agree with `Not a real-world example`. But details needed to be given to adequately answer the original question. I personally disagree with all your other points.

Comment: @PabloAriel Given the original question a copy needs to be a true copy. Thus neither `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` would actually work (without additional code). unique_ptr would simply prevent the copy and shared_ptr does not give you a new copy but shared data. Now I can see using `B m_b` is definitely better than using `B* m_b` in **most** cases but the OP has chosen an implementation that uses a pointer for a reason (otherwise the simpler solution would have been used). So saying `class A{B m_b={};}` is not an answer.

Comment: @PabloAriel Understanding how to wrap new/delete is a good idea for all programers. Though best advice is still with using std::"smart pointer" as suggested with the first example.

Comment: @PabloAriel Based on your comments I have the feeling you have also not discovered the Copy and Swap idiom I suggest you do some research on that.

Comment: @PabloAriel Based on your comments I have the feeling you don't understand how to write a standard `swap()` method. You should probably learn the idiomatic way to write swap.

Comment: I do know about the copy and swap idiom. I also know how to avoid copying data redundantly and unnecessary memory allocations. I don't think there is ever the need to use "new" in a constructor nowadays, but you're free to provide a real-world example if you think there are times in which it's unavoidable.

Comment: @PabloAriel What about `std::vector<>` I bet it has a new in its constructor :-) . Basically any time you are creating a container or a smart pointer these are necessary. Just because the standard library has the most common ones does not mean you will never come across situations where the standard ones are not sufficient (so you should know how to do it when you need to). Though admittedly those will be very rare. Everybody should try and create a container/smart pointer (not just for the learning experience, but also to understand how hard they are to do correctly).

Comment: @PabloAriel Now I will be the first to say that in modern C++ you should not be using new/delete (especially when talking to beginners). But when you are in real life and have the experience these things do come up and you should know how to use them. The statement `I don't think there is ever the need to use "new" in a constructor nowadays` is just wrong. Sure it is rare but not understanding how to do it when you are experienced is an issue. Don't do it when you inexperienced but real life is a lot more complicated and thus experienced user will need to know this.

Comment: Ok, they may need to know it exists and that people do such things, but also they need to know it's not the way they should do it. Even something like `std::vector` shouldn't have any allocations in its default constructor, only in resize() operations such as copy constructors, but that's a different kind of constructor. Even then, I use `malloc()` and placement new in order to allocate memory larger than the one requested for faster `push()`, and there are no matching `delete`s for such `new`s.

Comment: @PabloAriel You need to study more if you are using `malloc()`!!!! (thats a memory allocation system from a completely different language). Yes `std::vector<>` needs allocation in the default constructor and a deallocation in the destructor!!!!! Please read more about RAII !!!!! But now you are **also** changing the discussion to the allocation of the elements in the container, sure they need the use of placement new and also require you to manually call the destructor. **BUT** that has nothing to do with this discussion. Why are you trying to build a straw man?

Comment: `but also they need to know it's not the way they should do it.` Thats a very overall broad statement. You need to know how to do it because every now and then you **will** need to do it. Now most of the time you will not need to do it (and when you do I would expect my developers to justify it). But the real life is not as simple as you seem to think it is things are not as simple and cut and dried as you seem to think.  You need to know how to do it because it is something you will use.

Comment: I never saw a situation in which you need to do it and I have plenty of developments as example, from web services to 3d games which are available on github. Also, `malloc()` is still part of C++ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc), and you need to use it in order to take advantage of placement new which enable important optimizations, though I don't even use that as I have a wrapper for enforcing aligned malloc in the different platforms. My code contains custom smart pointers and std::vector-like classes but the default constructor only initializes members to zero/null.

Comment: @PabloAriel You don't need to use it to use placement new. You can use the C++ allocators. `malloc` is part of C. Read the page you linked: It even uses a potentially different memory allocation area. It just happens that there are bindings from C++ to the C language (like there are bindings from nearly every language to C).

Comment: @PabloAriel Sorry this is a classic argument from incredulity: `I never saw a situation in which you need to do it `. I have been doing this a long time. **RAII** is the primary mechanism that C++ developers need to learn. I have written several articles on how to do this correctly: See: https://lokiastari.com/series/ the section of vectors and smart pointers where I walk through doing them correctly. You should definitely learn how to do it. This is a skill you will need if you want to continue as a C++ developer.

Comment: I know how to do RAII. I use it when it makes sense, such as for mutex locks and file handles. Nothing that you would ever new() in the default constructor, however. My framework includes its own smart pointer implementations and other raii facilities and if you have any critics to it they will be more than welcome. Also, using C headers leads to faster builds than compiling C++ template files.

Comment: @PabloAriel RAII Is for anything where there is `create/doSomthing/destory` pattern. They are basically the standard idiom in C++ and used for everything. If you are not writing destructors then you are probably doing something wrong. C headers are not great because they are inconsistent on if they put things in the std namespace. C header files => always global namespace (sometimes std namespace). C++ header files => always std namespace. If you want to swap speed at compile time for safety that's a false saving as the cost of debugging the resulting issues will be orders of magnitude larger

Comment: PS. Why would you use RAII for mutex locks `std::lock_guard` and files `std::fstream` but not for memory `std::vector`, when all of these are already in standard? Is there something magical about memory and not other resources?

Comment: I think none of those classes do `new()` in their default constructor and they shouldn't if they want to avoid plenty of unnecessary allocations, but you're free to look for the code and share it so everyone can see how I'm wrong. ie. with a real world example.

Comment: No worries about the debugging. It is solved by using my own implementations of things like std::vector. I never use naked arrays or raw pointers.

Answer (score 20):

[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) - Resource Acquisition Is Initialization

Comment: though typically you'd use a smart pointer to do the RAII for you rather than code it yourself

Comment: Not necessarily. Writing the RAII class yourself gives you much better control over lifetime management for the resource. Smart pointers are just one of many possible examples of RAII. The idiom covers *far* more than `boost::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

This technique is best known as **RAII - Resource Allocation Is Initialization**. It has its own [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raii) on this site.

Alternative, arguably more intuitive names have been suggested, for example:

- [**UDSTMR - Using Destructor Semantics To Manage Resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/understanding-the-meaning-of-the-term-and-the-concept-raii-resource-acquisiti/712649#comment22675266_712649).
- [**UTSTTC - Using The Stack To Trigger Cleanup**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/please-help-us-non-c-developers-understand-what-raii-is).
- [**LECLOEIGU - Lifetime Equals Class Lifetime Or Else It Gets Ugly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about#comment19427629_161179). Note: The original suggestion, LECCLEOEIGU - Lifetime Equals C++ Class Lifetime Or Else It Gets Ugly, had an extra E which was a typo; and included an extra C for the language name, which I prefer to omit here because it already known.