# deleting object pointer referring by two pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have an object say.

```
ClassA *obj1 = new ClassA;

ClassA *ptr1 = obj1;
ClassA *ptr2 = obj1;
```

When I do `delete ptr1;`, will it affect `ptr2`? If so what can be the correct solution for this?

Comment: I assume `obj2` is suppose to be `obj1`? In any case, the solution is [stop manually managing memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681455/what-is-the-philosophy-of-managing-memory-in-c/3681471#3681471).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming `obj2` is supposed to be `obj1`)

`ClassA *x` defines a *pointer* that can point to objects of type `ClassA`. A pointer isn't an object itself.

`new ClassA` allocates (and constructs) an actual object of type `ClassA`.

So the line `Class A *obj1 = new ClassA;` defines a pointer `obj1` and then sets it to point to a newly allocated object of type `ClassA`.

The line `Class A *ptr1 = obj1;` defines a pointer `ptr1` and then sets it to point to the same thing `obj1` is pointing to, that is, the `ClassA` object we just created.

After the line `Class A *ptr2 = obj1;`, we have three pointers (`obj1`, `ptr1`, `ptr2`) all pointing to the same object.

If we do `delete ptr1;` (or equivalently, `delete obj1;` or `delete ptr2;`), we destroy the pointed to object. After doing this, any pointer that was pointing to the object is made invalid (which answers your first question: yes, it will affect `ptr2` in the sense that `ptr2` won't be pointing to a valid object afterwards).

The correct solution depends on what you're trying to achieve:

- If you want two copies of the object, assuming `ClassA` has a copy constructor, do `ClassA *ptr2 = new ClassA(*obj1);`. You will need to `delete` this new object separately when you are done with it!
- If you want two pointers to the same object, consider using something like `boost::shared_ptr` (google it)

Hmm, that's alot of text for such a simple q+a. Ah well.

Comment: Thnx a lot now got that concept.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `obj2` is supposed to be `obj1` then yes, calling delete on `ptr1` will leave `ptr2` with invalid data.  The solution to this would be to set `ptr1` to `NULL` if you want to empty it with out losing the object pointed to in `ptr2`.

Delete is just for when you want to completely free the memory.  If you still want to retain the object and data pointed to, but want to clear the pointer, set it to `NULL` (or `(void *) 0`).

Comment: In C++, `NULL` is just 0 (or equivalent), not a pointer type.