# Memory Handling C++ using Normal Pointer

Tags: c++

I have a situation like below in which I have some problem in freeing the memory. Basically I have a vector that holds pointer to objects from classA. I have another classB that store the pointer of classA from the vector. It would make use of the objB. The problem is I need to operate on the vector to erase the pointer.

So how could I free the memory of objA as in the description below?

1. pass by value the objA and make a copy in objB?
2. delete the pointer to objA in the destructor of objB? ( I would not want to do that as well because it is only when the logic is fulfilled, I need to erase the pointer and delete the object. Otherwise, I would like to keep the object.

   vectorA< classA*> vt;
   .... storing multiple pointer to objects to vector

   classB* objB = new classB(vt.at(pos));

   some logic performed. If it is fulfilled, need to erase a particular object from vector.

   vt.erase(pos); ==> how do I free the memory if I deleted the pointer here? 
   I could not call delete here because objB might need to use the objA later.

   classB::classB(classA* objA){
    this->objA = objA;
   }

So there any way to free the memory using Normal pointer as of the case above?
As some of the replies directed me to using smart pointer, my question is are there any penalty imposed on the performance by using smart pointer? (like C# indeterministic garbage collector is not really ideal for performance critical application).

Comment: [Use smart pointers and RAII.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681455/what-is-the-philosophy-of-managing-memory-in-c/3681471#3681471)  Then you don't have to worry about managing things yourself.  Really, it's much, much, much easier and far less error prone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least offhand, it sounds like you're looking for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have no way of handling it in normal pointer? This is because the vector class with the normal pointer is already in place and used... I am just trying to extend the code...

Comment: It can be done with a raw pointer, but you're probably going to end up simulating most of the functionality of a shared_ptr (or something on that order) by the time you make it work right.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a **single owner** of the `A` objects, either `vt` or `objB`.

My inclination is towards the former.

Classes like `objB` who want to use the `A *` can use as `vt.at( pos )` as you mentioned, but they should *not* keep a copy of the `A *`.

Comment: There are situations in which you do need shared ownership, and that's what `shared_ptr<>` is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or later then you can use `std::tr1::shared_ptr`. If you don't, you can use `boost::shared_ptr` (the same class).

Store the shared_ptr in your vector, then you don't need to worry about deallocation of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, perhaps before you changed your question, a [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) sounds like a good idea for the vector.  You might want also to use a [weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) in the classB reference so that the vector is in control of the lifetime (classB would have to be able to handle when the  weak_ptr goes stale).

For deallocation, by default shared_ptr deletes when the reference count goes to 0.  You can specify a custom deleter for your shared_ptr that gives more control over what actually happens.  Check out the [delayed deallocation technique](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#delayed) for Boost shared_ptrs.