# C++:boost: pass by value parameter

Tags: c++

I use smart pointer from Boost library. Suppose I have this object:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new A);

a->fileName = "/temp";
```

In the class B, I have:

```
bool open(A *a);
```

and

```
private: boost::shared_ptr<A> myA;
```

Then I declare an object B:

```
boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B());

b->open(a.get());

bool B::open(A *a)
{
  *B::myA = *a;
}
```

Those demonstration above is about pass by value parameter. Compiling is fine but when I run it, it gave this error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: typename boost::detail::shared_ptr_traits<T>::reference boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = NameSpaceABC::Common::A]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted
```

And for the same question above, what should I change to have: pass by reference parameters? As I am a C# and Java programmer, I just have switched to C++ for a quick project. I am not familiar with using pointers and Boost Smart pointer.

Thanks in advance and I am very appreciated about your help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging `VImageInputStream::open` to see if either `myA` of `a` is 0 ? The boost assertion is pretty clear : you are dereferencing an empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the answer from Space_C0wb0y below. It is working fine but I am not sure whether it is value passing parameter or  reference passing parameter? and how to write 'delete' in destructor for the smart pointer. Thanks in advance

Comment: The "smart" part of smart pointers is that you don't have to write `delete` anymore. They'll do that for you. When the last `shared_ptr<A>` goes away, it deletes the A object.

Comment: Review your questions to accept answers ppl gave you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a smart-pointer pointer for an object once, you should use it for that object always. In your case, `open` should look like this:

```
bool B::open(boost::shared_ptr<A> a) {
    myA = a;
}
```

This way you would have reference semantics for the object passed to `open`. Your code example tried to assign the object, not the reference. In that case you have to make sure that `myA` already contains a valid object of type `A` (preferably in the constructor):

```
B::B() : myA(boost::make_shared<A>()) {}
```

And then you can write your `open` method like this:

```
bool B::open(const A & a) {
    *myA = a;
}
```

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/please-help-us-non-c-developers-understand-what-raii-is) to understand how `shared_ptr`s work.

Comment: Oh Ok. I see, but this is value passing parameter, right? if yes, and how about reference passing parameter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Joesy: The `shared_ptr` *is* the reference. And you pass the reference by value. `shared_ptr` should always be passed by value, because only that way their reference counting works.

Comment: I don't think the `shared_ptr` has to be passed by value in the first case. The end result is that you'd have two pointers to the same object. There is no need to have temporarily a third pointer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing a shared_ptr that is not pointing to an object.

It seems to me that there might be two possible scenarios.

1) You want to share the A object in main and B. Then you should pass a `shared_ptr` to open.

```
bool B::open(const shared_ptr<A>& a)
{
    myA = a;
}

//called with
b->open(a);
```

2) You want B to make a copy of the value. Then it might make sense to pass the object.

```
bool B::open(const A& a)
{
    myA.reset(new A(a));
}

//called with
b->open(*a);
```

Or perhaps, if `myA` is already pointing to an object, you won't need to allocate a new one.

```
bool B::open(const A& a)
{
    if (myA)
        *myA = a;
    else
        myA.reset(new A(a));
}
```