# create new instance of a class without "new" operator

Tags: c++, class

Just a simple question.  As the title suggests, I've only used the "new" operator to create new instances of a class, so I was wondering what the other method was and how to correctly use it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can also have *automatic* instances of your class, that doesn't use `new`, as:

```
class A{};

//automatic 
A a;             

//using new
A *pA = new A();

//using malloc and placement-new
A *pA = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
pA = new (pA) A();

//using ONLY placement-new
char memory[sizeof(A)];
A *pA = new (memory) A();
```

The last two are using [placement-new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) which is slightly different from just *new*. placement-new is used to construct the object by calling the constructor. In the third example, `malloc` only allocates the memory, it doesn't call the constructor, that is why *placement-new* is used to call the constructor to construct the object.

Also note how to delete the memory.

```
  //when pA is created using new
  delete pA;

  //when pA is allocated memory using malloc, and constructed using placement-new
  pA->~A(); //call the destructor first
  free(pA); //then free the memory

  //when pA constructed using placement-new, and no malloc or new!
  pA->~A(); //just call the destructor, that's it!
```

---

To know what is placement-new, read these FAQs:

- [What is "placement new" and why would I use it?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) (FAQ at parashift.com)
- [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new) (FAQ at stackoverflow.com)

Comment: +1: I was wondering what the correct term for *not dynamically allocated* was. *automatic* - Thanks!

Comment: Also, to appreciate the advantages of using automatic instances, you need to know about [RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/).

Comment: An `auto` variable is also sometimes called a `stack` variable. How many programmers actually use the `auto` keyword anyway?

Comment: The third example doesn't always work, because the character array `memory` isn't guaranteed to have the proper alignment for an `A` object.

Comment: @Derek: What that has to do with the object? `memory` is not the object. Or how do you think placement-new work?

Comment: @Loadmaster: As I commented to a now deleted answer, calling an automatic variable a stack variable can in some cases be incorrect, for instance when such a variable is member of a heap-allocated object.

Comment: @Nawaz: @Derek is correct, a `char[]` array is not guaranteed to be aligned correctly to be converted (placement new'd) into an object. `memory` is not the object, but it will contain the object after it is `new'd`, and therefore must provide the proper alignment for the object.

Comment: @Loadmaster: That doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain how one should use placement-new?

Comment: Your link to parashift.com shows a *forbidden* error message.

Answer (score 5):

You can just declare a normal variable:

```
YourClass foo;
```

Comment: Assuming it has a default constructor.

Comment: Where can I find more information on a "normal variable"?

Answer (score 2):

Any of the usual ways: as a local or static variable, or as
a temporary.  In general, the only times you use `new` in C++ is
when the object has identity and a lifetime which doesn't
correspond to a scope, or when it is polymorphic.  (There are
exceptions, of course, but not many.)  If the object can be
copied, it's usually preferable to use local instances, copying
those as needed.  (Just like you would for `int`, in fact.)

Answer (score 0):

Using malloc will give you the same result as new, just without calling the constructor.

Comment: Not completely wrong, so no -1... This is somewhat correct only if constructor does nothing and class does not have any virtual methods...