# Does using index brackets for a pointer dereference it?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

Does using index brackets for a pointer also dereference it? And why does printing the 0th index of this pointer twice end up printing two different things?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int *p;

void fn() {
    int num[1];
    num[0]=99;
    p = num;
}

int main() {
    fn();
    cout << p[0] << "  " << p[0];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> does using index brackets for a pointer also dereference it?

Correct, pointer arithmetic is equivalent to array index. `p[index]` is the same as `*(p+index)`.

> Why does printing the 0th index of this pointer twice end up printing two different things?

Because you are using `p` to point to a local variable (`num`) whose scope ends when the `fn()` function ends. What you observed is **undefined behavior**. Returning a pointer to local variable is bad practice and must be avoided.

Btw, just to see the scope effect, if you move the definition of the `num` array to outside the `fn()` function, then you will see consistent `cout` behavior.

Alternatively, as @Marc.2377 suggested, to avoid global variables (which is bad practice), you can allocate the variable in the heap (`int* num = new int[1];`). It would then be ok to return pointer `p` from `fn()`, but DON'T forget to call `delete[] p` in `main()` afterwards.

Comment: Or also `int* num = new int[1];` within `fn()` (though that is definitely not recommended and should only be used to confirm the scope effect)

Comment: @Marc.2377 that's a good point to avoid global vars, I edited the answer following your comment - tks

Comment: @artm Hah nice, thanks for including it. It's important to point out, however, that relying on main() to execute `delete` - or, for that matter, not having `new` and `delete` encapsulated as dictated by RAII [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/3258851), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/712639/3258851) - is error-prone and not best practice. But of course `unique_ptr<int> num(new int[1]);` would not work for demonstration purposes...

Comment: @Marc.2377 `unique_ptr` supports arrays, you just have to specify an array type in the template parameter, eg: `std::unique_ptr<int[]> num(new int[1]);` This specialization uses `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh yeah, but my point is that using `unique_ptr` will defeat the purpose of my previous suggestion, which was intended as a "hack" to make `num` survive the end of `fn()` scope.

Comment: Doesn't `p[i]` also take the type of `p` into consideration? Like `p[i]` and `*(p + sizeof(int) * i)` would be equivalent if `p` is an `int*`?

Comment: @sisisisi that's incorrect. `p[i]` is the same as `p + i` because pointer arithmetic already takes into account of the type, so you never have to apply the `sizeof` as you wrote

Answer (score 3):

> does using index brackets for a pointer also dereference it?

yes, it does. `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`.

It is undefined behavior to access the out of scope local variable `num`. Essentially `p` is pointing to a local variable `num`. After returning from `fn()`, `num` goes out of scope, so anything can be stored at its address.

Comment: isn't it global scope?

Comment: `p` isn't a local variable. It's global.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are allocated contiguous memory location ( all elements are stored contiguously), so A[i] ( the element present at ith index of the array) will be i memory units away from the base address of the array A.
Hence A[i] is equivalent to *( A + i ).

The pointer stores the address and not the contents within. So, the local variable ceases to exist outside the function ( local scope), thereby giving different results outside the function.