# How can object construction of a class be stopped if a parameter passed is found to be wrong?

Tags: c++

```
class Date {
    Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    }
}

int main() {
    Date d = Date(100, 2, 1990);
}
```

Here value(100) passed to day is not right, My question is how 'day' parameter can be checked in constructor to prevent creation of object

Answer (score 10):

Throw an exception.

Comment: Or, you could call `std::exit`, but that's a bit drastic.  :-)

Comment: Drastic, indeed. All the OP wants is to prevent object creation, not destroy his entire process.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Date
{
public:
    Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        if (day < 1 || day > 31) { // oversimplified check!
            throw std::invalid_argument("day");
        }
    }
};

int main()
try
{
    Date d = Date(100, 2, 1990);
}
catch ( const std::exception& error )
{
    std::cerr << error.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Nice short example. BTW, your `main` is missing some `{}`.

Comment: @Ken: It's called a function try block, it's perfectly legal, though he is missing a few things(a semi-colon at the end of his class, and his constructor is private).

Comment: But I think it is not a good practice to throw exception from constructor

Comment: @sukumar: Why do you think that?

Comment: @Benjamin: Ok, didn't know about that. Looks a little funky, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @sukumar: it doesn't matter if it's a good practice or not.  OP specifically requested "My question is how 'day' parameter can be checked in constructor to **prevent creation of object**".

Comment: @sukumar: It is a very good practice. C++ has been designed to support it. You might be confused with exceptions from a **de**structor. Those are bad; destroying an object should not fail. There's no digital afterlife, if you die you die.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your own "Date" function.

Just validate the arguments inside the constructor, and throw an exception if they're invalid.

Answer (score -3):

Take another example

```
class base 
{
    public:
       base(int no, int month) 
       {
          p = new int(no);
          // some code
          // now here you have checked value of month and threw exception
       }
private:
    int *p;
};
```

If exception is thrown from constructor, user of the class has to be very careful to prevent memory leak. Therefore it is not a good practice. Think to solve it in other way

Comment: No, One should use **RAII** so that the resources are deallocated automatically and no explicit deallocations are needed.

Comment: Actually, throwing an exception from a constructor - if the object cannot be created (for example, because of invalid arguments) is generally an EXTREMELY good idea.  James' original reply is the correct reply.  Please consider that if you follow good RAII design principles, this need NOT risk causing any kind of resource link or inconsistency.  Please look at these links:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about     http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Exception_Handling#Constructors_and_destructors

Comment: PS, Sukumar: Please mark James' or Andre's answer "accepted" after you've read the two links and satisfied yourself they're giving you good advice :)

Comment: Throwing an exception is standard practice: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8 Being careful to prevent memory leaks is **not** a job for the user of the class; it's a job - an absolutely mandatory one - for the designer of the class. Fortunately, it is not all that hard to get right, if you use proper tools and idioms.