# Why use a single incrementer class

Tags: oop

Below code are found in WebKit:

```
RefPtr<Element> element = pendingScript.releaseElementAndClear();
if (ScriptElement* scriptElement = toScriptElement(element.get())) {
    NestingLevelIncrementer nestingLevelIncrementer(m_scriptNestingLevel);
    IgnoreDestructiveWriteCountIncrementer ignoreDestructiveWriteCountIncrementer(m_document);
    //Do something else...
    }
}
```

NestingLevelIncrementer is a simple class, which increase the counter in construction and decrease it in destruction. You could check the implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/webkit-mirror/source/browse/Source/WebCore/html/parser/NestingLevelIncrementer.h?r=c28243e39fb5dd43e94135a9163171cc22341a65).

In this scrap, I think that is similar with increasing and reducing the number directly. Perhaps the only benefit is no matter to reduce the number then, but one new class is introduced.

Any other reason to use this pattern?

Comment: Sounds like dynamic binding to me.

Comment: Standardisation and clarity: use the same philosophy/programming style in all of the code, even if it may be overkill in some places. That makes life a lot easier for your fellow programmers.

Comment: Using a such class allows to change the behaviour if needed. For instance adding more instructions in the constructor/destructor, for further versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent is for the increment to be reversed no matter how the `something else` concludes; the stack variable will be destroyed when the method returns or an exception is thrown.

An alternative approach in other languages would use `try...finally`; see this for more discussion on RAII in C++ vs. finally:

[Does C++ support 'finally' blocks? (And what's this 'RAII' I keep hearing about?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about)