# Boost Unit Test: Catch an unsuccessful Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am running a test where a usb device is opened, a packet is sent and received and it is closed again.
It looks like this:

```
void TestCase1(void)
{
 int recv;
 BOOST_REQUIRE(initDevice());
 BOOST_REQUIRE(openDevice());
 BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(receiveData(), 5);
 BOOST_REQUIRE(closeDevice());
 BOOST_REQUIRE(uninitDevice());
}
```

Now whenever there is an error in the `receiveData()` call and the Check for '5' fails, the `closeDevice()` and `uninitDevice()` are not called anymore and I cannot use the device in the next test. Is there a way to handle this? Maybe catch an exception and close and uninit the device in that catch scope too? Or is this a complete wrong approach?
I am pretty new to unit testing. So any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is opening actual usb ports a sensible thing to do in a *unit* test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one of the key concepts within modern C++, [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about), to help keep initDevice / uninitDevice and openDevice/closeDevice tied together:

```
class USBDeviceHandler
{
public: 
    USBDeviceHandler()
    : initDeviceHandle { ::initDevice()), &::uninitDevice },
      openDeviceHandle { ::openDevice()), &::closeDevice }
    {
    }

    using init_handle = std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::uninitDevice)>;
    using open_handle = std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&::closeDevice)>;

    init_handle initDeviceHandle;
    open_handle openDeviceHandle;
};

void TestCase1(void)
{
 int recv;
 USBDeviceHandler device; //init/open is called upon construction
 BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(receiveData(), 5);
}//close/uninit is called upon destruction
```

This is based off the example given in [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: Is USBWrapper supposed to be the constructor for USBDeviceHandler?

Comment: @doctorlove - oops, fixed. I changed the name of the helper class halfway through writing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BOOST_CHECK` and `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL` when you want to report a condition not being satisfied, yet still continue the test.  In this case, perhaps the first two items should be "REQUIRE"d, and the last three should be "CHECK"ed.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off doing things that must happen first in a fixture setup and tidying up in a tear down function. Obviously using OO with RAII and putting the `receiveData` as a class method would avoid this.

Alternatively, `BOOST_CHECK` will check the condition and continue the test if it fails which would avoid the problem you have wherein `BOOST_REQUIRE` stops the rest of the test executing.