# how to make sure locker be unlock in c++? which solution is better

Tags: c++, locking

there are two solutions:

A:

```
lock()
try{
    action()
}catch(...)
{
    unlock()
    throw;
}
unlock()
```

B:

```
{
LockObject lockObject;
action();
}
```

LockObject's constuctor will call lock(),its de-construtor will call unlock().

So what's the better solution or is there any other better solution?

ps: in linux c++, it doesn't support keywords finally. So I have to make decision for this issue.

Comment: Why don't you call `~Lock()` instead of `UnLock()`?

Comment: Which looks better to you?

Comment: both looks good, but it must has better one so I asked this issue.

Comment: If I will be a programmer of this code I will use case A with all exception handling which will save my code form undefined behavior.

Comment: @AnkitB, but solution B sees can do unlock after } too

Comment: @jiafu But if any exception came in `action()` your code will  show an `runtime` error as a programmer we have to keep in mind that it should not came.

Comment: @AnkitB，but it still can unlock due to deconstruter be called?

Comment: @jiafu I don`t think so. Because if any exception thrown by program/Application at `runtime` the memory which is allocated becomes garbage.

Comment: @AnkitB, you're wrong; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization and here's a SO q&a to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about

Comment: @jiafu Thanks for such a nice documentation it helps me to furnish my knowledge.

Comment: @jiafu, how are your `lock()/unlock()` methods implemented? In other words, do you have a `pthread_mutex_t` that sits as some static variable in a file/class/struct that you then lock? If this is the case, your `LockObject` might not function the way you're thinking??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is a special programming idiom called Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII), and it can be applied in several programming languages such as C++, D, Ada.

When you want to acquire resource, you use initialization. And you release resource in destructor.

It is a well known idiom and it's also a good design in C++. In fact, C++ standard library uses it quite often.

For example,

```
// global mutex
std::mutex mutex;

void f()
{

    // lock mutex
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    //do something might throw exception
    //...

    //do not unlock mutex, it will be unlocked by lock_guard destructor  
}
```

Comment: can you give the full definition for the std::lock_guard? I will accept this answer. Many thanks to you.

Comment: is stl::lock_guard contained in stl library?

Comment: Hi jiafu, lock_guard is in c++11. If you don't have a c++11 compiler, you can use boost library. They are almost identical. A web reference of lock guard is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

Comment: The design of lock_guard is quite straight-forward. Basically, lock_guard requires the resource it can lock to have two methods, lock() and unlock(), once your resource class has these two methods, it can be used with lock_guard. lock_guard will call lock() in constructor and call unlock() in destructor.