# std::unique_ptr for C functions that need free

Tags: c++, c++11

Think to a C function that return something that must be `free`d, for example the POSIX's `strdup()`. I want to use that function in C++11 and avoid any chance of leaks, is this a correct way?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char const* t { "Hi stackoverflow!" };
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>
        t_copy { strdup(t), std::free };

    std::cout << t_copy.get() << " <- this is the copy!" <<std::endl;
}
```

Assuming it makes sense, it is possible to use a similar pattern with non-pointers? For example for the POSIX's function `open` that returns an `int`?

Comment: This question finally explained to me why deleters are useful.

Comment: The question uses unspecified/undefined behavior and is not guaranteed to work, because it takes the address of a function from the standard library.  My solution is guaranteed to work, because it only calls free instead of taking its address.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

What you have is extremely likely to work in practice, but not strictly correct. You can make it even more likely to work as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(std::free) *>
    t_copy { strdup(t), std::free };
```

The reason is that the function type of `std::free` is not guaranteed to be `void(void*)`. It is guaranteed to be callable when passed a `void*`, and in that case to return `void`, but there are at least two function types that match that specification: one with C linkage, and one with C++ linkage. Most compilers pay no attention to that, but for correctness, you should avoid making assumptions about it.

However, even then, this is not strictly correct. As pointed out by @PeterSom in the comments, C++ allows implementations to e.g. make `std::free` an overloaded function, in which case both your and my use of `std::free` would be ambiguous. This is not a specific permission granted for `std::free`, it's a permission granted for pretty much any standard library function. To avoid this problem, a custom function or functor (as in his answer) is required.

> Assuming it makes sense, it is possible to use a similar pattern with non-pointers?

Not with `unique_ptr`, which is really specific to pointers. But you could create your own class, similar to `unique_ptr`, but without making assumptions about the object being wrapped.

Comment: Using decltype() really underline what deleter you want to use and I like it and maybe it is worthy another question. However, is the type of ``extern "C" { void f(void*) }`` and ``void f(void*)`` different? I thought the difference was only in the symbol name. At very lease you can use the same kind of function pointers...

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni: Yes, they are different types, and you can't (portably) use the same pointer type.

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni A few implementations really complain about `extern "C" { void f(); } void (*fp)() = f;` with a message about assignment from an incompatible pointer type. I think I remember reading that HP's is one implementation that flat out rejects it, but I have no way to verify that. Sun's (now Oracle's) is another implementation that pays attention to it, but it allows such implicit conversions with a warning (and that I have seen myself).

Comment: You are right gentlemen. In my system ``std::is_same`` return true for the two ``decltype``s, but I checked the standard and yes different linkage means different type. There is always something to learn.

Comment: If the standard says that C functions have different types than C++ functions with the same signature, then it's the standard that's braindead in this regard. Whether a function has C or C++ linkage has nothing to do with how this function is implemented, the only difference is whether name mangling is applied or not. And the name of a thing has nothing to do with the type of the thing. Worse: there is only one syntax to write down the type of a function pointer. Taken literally, that means I can't even declare a C function pointer without resorting to `decltype`!

Comment: @cmaster They could legitimately have different calling conventions, the C convention for compatibility, the C++ convention a better one. As for avoiding `decltype`: create typedefs inside `extern "C"` blocks. But you'd be surprised how little it's needed.

Comment: @hvd No, I'm not surprised: Even though I know of some use cases where they are of crucial importance, I know how rarely these use cases come up. As to the calling conventions: Yes, you are right, a compiler *could* use the wording of the standard to use different calling conventions. Nevertheless, it *should* not do that as that would unnecessarily introduce a ton of extra complexity, and will likely break quite a few programs that rely on function pointers. I, for one, prefer the same syntax to mean the same thing in all contexts. That's what makes a language KISS.

Comment: @cmaster That's like arguing that compilers should not optimise signed integer arithmetic, should not assume array indices are less than the array length, etc. either. In general, if compilers can make programs faster by assuming no undefined behaviour, experience has shown that many will do so. At which point you're perfectly within your rights to choose not to use such an implementation: there are still others that don't do so. Different people have different wishes for their compilers.

Comment: @hvd Not really. It's more like arguing that the expression `42` should not be of type `int_c` in a C function, and of type `int_c++` in a C++ function, with no means to distinguish between the two other than the `decltype` keyword, and no means to convert the one into the other. This may sound abstruse, but in reality it's really very close to the issue with the function pointers. From a language design standpoint, such context sensitivity is an abomination that should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @cmaster I thought you were arguing that the mere idea of language linkage was a horrible one, but your last comment seems more like you don't object to language linkage per se, but merely object to the lack of an explicit syntax for specifying language linkage of a function type. If that's what you mean, that's a fair point, and I think I would agree that the language would be improved with an explicit syntax. But you're wrong that `decltype` is needed. I put `decltype` in my answer because it's the easiest way here, not because it's the only way.

Comment: @hvd I object to both. One type `int` = good, two types `int_c` & `int_c++` = bad, two indistinguishable types `int` = evil. Same story for function pointers. Whether two types are necessary depends only on the implementation details (and it's not necessary for both `int`s and function pointers), how good/bad such a split is, is a question that's purely on the language level (and I believe it's a really bad idea). I have argued on both levels with different arguments, but the result is the same: Splitting function pointer types in this way is a bad design decision.

Comment: Using decltype(free) adds overhead of an extra pointer to the unique_ptr . See my answer for a solution without that space overhead.

Comment: As of C++2a the ISO standard makes it explicit (it was an implicit thing before) one is not allowed to take the address of almost all functions mentioned in the C++  standard (see https://wg21.link/p0551 , exceptions are for example the iostream manipulators). This includes all functions "inherited" from C. Thus the above example is invalid and my answer below is valid, because it calls free() and not takes its address.

Comment: @PeterSom You're overstating your point, but the point is valid. It's not UB (at least not yet, not even implicitly). It's not guaranteed to compile, but if it does compile, I don't see any way in which it's not guaranteed to behave as intended. Will edit.

Comment: sorry, it is "unspecified" in the standard. But if it compiles now and today it is not guaranteed to do so tomorrow, or with a different compiler.

Answer (score 46):

The original question (and [hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441139/779373)) introduce a per-pointer overhead, so such a `unique_ptr` is twice the size than one derived with `std::make_unique`. In addition, I would formulate the decltype directly:

```
std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)>
    t_copy { strdup(t), &std::free };
```

If one has many of those C-API-derived pointers that extra space can be a burden hindering adoption of safe C++ RAII for C++ code wrapping existing POSIX style APIs requiring to be `free()`d. Another problem that can arise, is when you use `char const` in the above situation, you get a compile error, because you can not automatically convert a `char const *` to the Parameter type of `free(void *)`.

I suggest to use a dedicated deleter type, not one built on the fly, so that the space overhead goes away and the required `const_cast` is also not a problem. A template alias then can easily be used to wrap C-API-derived pointers:

```
struct free_deleter{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T *p) const {
        std::free(const_cast<std::remove_const_t<T>*>(p));
    }
};
template <typename T>
using unique_C_ptr=std::unique_ptr<T,free_deleter>;
static_assert(sizeof(char *)==
              sizeof(unique_C_ptr<char>),""); // ensure no overhead
```

The example now becomes

```
unique_C_ptr<char const> t_copy { strdup(t) };
```

I will suggest that that mechanism should be made available in the C++ Core Guidelines support library ( maybe with a better naming ), so it can be made available for code bases transitioning to modern C++ ( success open ).

Comment: I know there are other more generic options to wrap deleter code into the unique_ptr's type, but they might be more involved and not as simple to understand and implement.

Comment: I like this answer and agree with most of it, except for saying my answer introduces overhead. It does not: it has the same overhead as what's in the question. I merely did not address that aspect (and hadn't thought of it, at least not when writing my answer).

Comment: Yes, the original question already had the unnecessary overhead. And I was adding my answer, becausethat overhead was used as an excuse for not using unique_ptr for the purpose, and because my suggestion was objected on the std mailing list as something to put into the C++ Standard. And yes, until a week ago,I also hadn't thought of this solution consciously.

Comment: If you agree that my answer is not what introduces the overhead, please edit your answer to no longer make that claim. For instance: "The answer <...> does not fix the per-pointer overhead, so..." would seem to me to not detract from the point of your answer.

Comment: see above. The original question and answer are undefined behavior, because they take the address of a standard library function, which is not defined in the standard. Implementors are free to provide other overloads or have wider parameter lists providing default arguments. Just calling a function from the standard library is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Hm. Wouldn't it be good for generality to invoke the dtor just in case it's not trivial? Otherwise, you could just use a void-pointer instead of a template...

Comment: s/undefined/unspecified/ behavior in my comment above.

Comment: I do not understand Deduplicator's comment.

Comment: Won't `template <typename T> void operator()(volatile const T *p) const { std::free(const_cast<T*>(p)); }` be faster to compile and shorter?

Answer (score 8):

> Assuming it makes sense, it is possible to use a similar pattern with
>   non-pointers? For example for the POSIX's function open that returns
>   an int?

Yes, it can be done. You need a "pointer" type that satisfies [the `NullablePointer` requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NullablePointer):

```
struct handle_wrapper {

    handle_wrapper() noexcept : handle(-1) {}
    explicit handle_wrapper(int h) noexcept : handle(h) {}
    handle_wrapper(std::nullptr_t)  noexcept : handle_wrapper() {}

    int operator *() const noexcept { return handle; }
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return *this != nullptr; }

    friend bool operator!=(const handle_wrapper& a, const handle_wrapper& b) noexcept {
        return a.handle != b.handle;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const handle_wrapper& a, const handle_wrapper& b) noexcept {
        return a.handle == b.handle;
    }

    int handle;
};
```

Note that we use -1 as the null handle value here because that's what `open()` returns on failure. It's also very easy to templatize this code so that it accepts other handle types and/or invalid values.

Then

```
struct posix_close
{
    using pointer = handle_wrapper;
    void operator()(pointer fd) const
    {
        close(*fd);
    }
};

int
main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int, posix_close> p(handle_wrapper(open("testing", O_CREAT)));
    int fd = *p.get();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cad469c24a84231).

Comment: Sounds correct, but if I need to write a class like that probably using _finally_ and a lambda is easier to read...

( _finally_ C++ implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25510879/1876111 )

Comment: Better yet, specialise `std::default_delete<handle_wrapper>` and create a function `wrap_open`, then a user can write simply `auto p = std::make_unique(wrap_open("testing", O_CREAT));`.

Answer (score 7):

Just to update the answer: C++20 allows lambdas in unevaluated contexts (like `decltype`), so there is no longer a need to even write a structure to call `std::free` to take advantage of empty base optimization. The following will do.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<T, decltype([](void *p) { std::free(p); })> ptr;
```

The trick is that such a lambda is default constructible.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that “such a lambda is default constructible” means “… in C++20”.

Answer (score 6):

> Assuming it makes sense, it is possible to use a similar pattern with
>   non-pointers? For example for the POSIX's function open that returns
>   an int?

Sure, using Howard's Hinnant [tutorial on unique_ptr](https://howardhinnant.github.io/unique_ptr03.html), we can see a motivating example:

```
// For open
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// For close
#include <unistd.h>

// For unique_ptr
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto handle_deleter = [] (int* handle) {
        close(*handle);
    };

    int handle = open("main.cpp", O_RDONLY);
    std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(handle_deleter)> uptr
        { &handle, handle_deleter };
}
```

Alternatively you can use a functor instead of a lambda:

```
struct close_handler
{
    void operator()(int* handle) const
    {
        close(*handle);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int handle = open("main.cpp", O_RDONLY);
    std::unique_ptr<int, close_handler> uptr
        { &handle };
}
```

The example can be further reduced if we use a typedef and a "factory" function.

```
using handle = int;
using handle_ptr = std::unique_ptr<handle, close_handler>;

template <typename... T>
handle_ptr get_file_handle(T&&... args)
{
    return handle_ptr(new handle{open(std::forward<T>(args)...)});
}

int main()
{
    handle_ptr hp = get_file_handle("main.cpp", O_RDONLY);
}
```

Comment: Since you're now storing a pointer to the handle, rather than the handle itself, there are possible problems with the object's lifetime if `handle` is destroyed before the `unique_ptr` is. You attempt to address that by using `new handle`, but in that case, don't forget that `close_handler` will need to not just close the handle, it also needs to free the memory, or you've got a leak.

Comment: In other words the `operator()` needs a `delete handle` to work correctly.

Comment: This works perfect with win32 functions too, e.g.: `std::unique_ptr<LPWSTR, decltype(&::LocalFree)> argv(CommandLineToArgvW(commandLine, &argc), ::LocalFree)`

Comment: In C++11/14/17, I only use classes with `operator()` (functors). Lambdas work great in C++20 as they’re default constructible if possible. The whole point of having a lambda in cases such as this is not giving the thing a name.