# smart pointer to manage socket file descriptor

Tags: sockets, c++11, smart-pointers

A smart pointer clears the memory if the pointer gets out of scope. I wanted to adapt this to a file descriptor, like a socket. There you need a user defined deleter, because close() is the function to free the file descriptor (fd) resources.

I found [this](http://asawicki.info/news_1494_unique_ptr_in_visual_c_2010.html) useful page, unfortunately, most approaches did not work for me. Below is a working solution I found up to now, which is a little nasty. Because uniqu_ptr expects a pointer I created int *fd to store the fd value, therefore, I had to close(*fd) and delete fd in my custom deleter.

**(1)** Is there a better way?

Options A and B, which are based on the hints provided by the mentioned web page, are much nicer but causing odd compiler errors.

**(2)** Does anyone know how to correctly use these alternatives?

I'm using Qt Creator 3.0.1 with CONFIG += c++11 option and gcc version 4.8.2

```cpp
#include "ccommhandler.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <memory>

#include <qdebug.h>

//for Option A and B
struct CloseHandleDeleter {
    typedef int pointer;
    void operator()(int handle) const
    {
    }
};

//custom deleter, working
class MyComplexDeleter
{

public:
    MyComplexDeleter() {}

    void operator()(int* ptr) const
    {
        qDebug() << "Deleting ";
        close(*ptr);
        delete ptr;
    }
};

CCommHandler::CCommHandler()
{
    //Option A doesn't work
    //std::unique_ptr<int, CloseHandleDeleter> file( socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) );
    //Option B doesn't work
    //std::unique_ptr<int, int()(int)> filePtr(  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) , close);

    MyComplexDeleter deleter;
    int *fd = new int;
    *fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    std::unique_ptr<int, MyComplexDeleter> p( fd , deleter);

}
```

**Edit:**

The posted answer by Nevin is right, it solves my initial problem.

The comment of learnvst caused to rethink my problem, and I have to say I may made it much more complex than needed, because the following simple class should also solve my problem of auto-free the memory of a resource or as in my case, to close the file descriptor:

```cpp
class SocketHandler
{
   int _fd;
 public:
   SocketHandler(int FD):_fd(FD){}
   ~SocketHandler() { if(_fd!=-1) close(_fd); }

   operator int() const { return _fd; }
};
```

Comment: Why not just wrap the socket stuff into a class and close the socket in the dtor? Then you do not need to use a deleter as everything will close out nicely when the smart pointer frees the resource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440953/stdunique-ptr-for-c-functions-that-need-free/27452707#27452707

Comment: A `unique_ptr` must hold a **pointer**.  `socket()` does not return a **pointer** on non-Windows platforms.  That is why options A and B do not work, but option C does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because fd isn't a pointer, I wouldn't try to pigeonhole it into `unique_ptr`. Instead, create a custom class whose interface is based on `unique_ptr`, as in (caution: totally untested):

```
class unique_fd
{
public:
    constexpr unique_fd() noexcept = default;
    explicit unique_fd(int fd) noexcept : fd_(fd) {}
    unique_fd(unique_fd&& u) noexcept : fd_(u.fd_) { u.fd_ = -1; }

    ~unique_fd() { if (-1 != fd_) ::close(fd_); }

    unique_fd& operator=(unique_fd&& u) noexcept { reset(u.release()); return *this; }

    int get() const noexcept { return fd_; }
    operator int() const noexcept { return fd_; }

    int release() noexcept { int fd = fd_; fd_ = -1; return fd; }
    void reset(int fd = -1) noexcept { unique_fd(fd).swap(*this); }
    void swap(unique_fd& u) noexcept { std::swap(fd_, u.fd_); }

    unique_fd(const unique_fd&) = delete;
    unique_fd& operator=(const unique_fd&) = delete;

    // in the global namespace to override ::close(int)
    friend int close(unique_fd& u) noexcept { int closed = ::close(u.fd_); u.fd_ = -1; return closed; }

private:
    int fd_ = -1;
};
```