# Can i somehow pass socket from winsock2.h to unique_ptr and make custom deleter for him?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, winsock2

Can i somehow pass socket from winsock2.h to unique_ptr and make custom deleter for him?
Like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<SOCKET,deleter> up(new socket(...), deleter);
```

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem? Also are you sure that you want a *pointer* to this socket? There are other options for wrappers than smart pointers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [smart pointer to manage socket file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614775/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, eg:

```cpp
struct SocketDeleter
{
    using pointer = SOCKET;
    // or, if nenecessary:
    // typedef SOCKET pointer;

    void operator()(SOCKET sckt) const {
        if (sckt != INVALID_SOCKET)
            closesocket(sckt);
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, SocketDeleter> up(socket(...));
```

However, `SOCKET` is not a pointer type (it is a `UINT`), and `std::unique_ptr` is not really intended to be used with non-pointer types.

You *could* do something like this instead:

```cpp
struct SocketDeleter
{
    void operator()(SOCKET* sckt) const {
        if (*sckt != INVALID_SOCKET)
            closesocket(sckt);
        delete sckt;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<SOCKET, SocketDeleter> up(new SOCKET(socket(...)), SocketDeleter{});
```

But that just gets ugly.

See [smart pointer to manage socket file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614775/) for alternative ways to design an RAII-style wrapper for a socket descriptor without using `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Normally I would agree, the only reason I didn't in this example is because I've seen some compilers that fail on `using` in this context. But I think they are old compilers, obviously it should work fine in modern compilers.