# Custom deletor for unique_ptr on gcc -std=c++14

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

This should get the the current working directory on Linux in RAII fashion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  //unique_ptr<const char> cwd (get_current_dir_name());
  //unique_ptr<const char, [](const char* ptr){ free(ptr) }> cwd (get_current_dir_name());

  unique_ptr<const char> cwd (get_current_dir_name());
  cout<<cwd.get()<<'\n';
  return 0;
}
```

It should'nt be using the default deleter because `get_current_dir_name()` returns `malloc`ed memory, which should be `free`d rather than `delete`d.

How can I get the custom deleter to work?
The commented-out lines are my failing attempts that won't compile
on gcc 4.9.2 (`-std=c++14`).

Comment: [std::unique_ptr for C functions that need free](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27440953/3953764)

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Thanks!