# Deduction guides for functions as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

[We can use `std::unique_ptr` to hold a pointer allocated with `malloc` which will be `free`d appropriately.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440953/stdunique-ptr-for-c-functions-that-need-free)
However, the resulting `std::unique_ptr`'s size will be 2 pointers, one for the pointer to the object and one for the pointer to the deleter function instead of the usual 1 pointer to object and an implicit `delete`. As one answer points out this can be avoided by writing a custom `Unique_ptr` that knows the proper deleter function. This function can be made known using a template parameter to support any deleter function like so:

```
template <class T, void (*Deleter)(T *)>
struct Unique_ptr {
    explicit Unique_ptr(T *t, void (*)(T *))
        : t{t} {}
    ~Unique_ptr() {
        Deleter(t);
    }
    //TODO: add code to make it behave like std::unique_ptr

    private:
    T *t{};
};

template <class T>
void free(T *t) {
    std::free(t);
}

char *some_C_function() {
    return (char *)malloc(42);
}

int main() {
    Unique_ptr<char, free> p(some_C_function(), free); //fine
    Unique_ptr q(some_C_function(), free);             //should be fine
                                                       //with the right
                                                       //deduction guide
}
```

This would be really nice if we could use deduction guides to not have to specify the template parameters. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the syntax right. These attempts fail to compile:

```
template <class T, auto Deleter>
Unique_ptr(T *, Deleter)->Unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;

template <class T, void (*Deleter)(T *)>
Unique_ptr(T *, void (*Deleter)(T *))->Unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;
```

Alternatively one could write `Unique_ptr<free> q(some_C_function());` in order to manually specify the function template parameter, but that creates issues with deducing `T`.

What is the correct deduction guide to make `Unique_ptr q(some_C_function(), free);` or `Unique_ptr<free> q(some_C_function());` compile?

Comment: Does your unique pointer support arrays? If yes, then you really *don't* want to have a deduction guide (can't differentiate between pointers from `new T()` and `new T[n]`)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is normally implemented with a specialisation when the deleter is `std::default_delete`. There will be no overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Why write your own `unique_ptr`? Just use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom delete pointer. With C++17, that's very straightforward:

```
template <auto Deleter>
struct func_deleter {
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T* ptr) const { Deleter(ptr); }
};

template <class T, auto D>
using unique_ptr_deleter = std::unique_ptr<T, func_deleter<D>>;
```

Or, as Yakk suggests, more generally:

```
template <auto V>
using constant = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(V)>, V>;

template <class T, auto D>
using unique_ptr_deleter = std::unique_ptr<T, constant<V>>;
```

which gets you to:

```
unique_ptr_deleter<X, free> ptr(some_c_api());
```

Sure, you have to actually write `X`, but you have no space overhead. In order to accomplish the same thing with deduction guides, you'd need to wrap the function deleter in order to lift it to a template parameter:

```
template <class T, auto D>
Unique_ptr(T*, func_deleter<D>) -> Unique_ptr<T, func_deleter<D> >;
```

Which would be used like:

```
Unique_ptr ptr(some_c_api(), func_deleter<free>());
```

I'm not sure that's necessarily better, and you run into all the same problems that led to the standard *not* having deduction guides for `std::unique_ptr` (i.e.: differentiating between pointers and arrays). YMMV.

Comment: The first version requires me to write `unique_ptr_deleter<char, free<char>> ptr(some_C_function());`. [The second version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/955df4ba3c15a7e4) I can't seem to get working at all.

Comment: @nwp Not `free<char>`, just `free`.

Comment: Why is `func_deleter` called `_deleter`?

Comment: To be specific, `template <auto f> using constant_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(f)>, f>;` seems less constrained and more universally useful than `func_deleter`.  And shorter.  (`()` support comes from operator pointer to function on integral constant of a function pointer.)  (And similar `constant` value-template natch)

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I like that better.

Comment: Clever? Yes. Readable? Mmmmm.... A simple `malloc_deleter` might be the answer here.

Comment: @Kerrek Sure, if all you need is `free`. But once you have multiple different C APIs, something like `unique_ptr_deleter` is really useful.