# Warning: ignoring attributes on template argument... in declaration of std::unique_ptr (-Wignored-attributes)

Tags: c++, posix, unique-ptr, gcc-warning

Using the pattern explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440953/stdunique-ptr-for-c-functions-that-need-free) as follows:

```
auto action = 
  std::unique_ptr< posix_spawn_file_actions_t, decltype(&posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy) > 
  { new posix_spawn_file_actions_t(), posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy };
```

triggers a `[-Wignored-attributes]` in gcc `v10.1.0` `-std=c++20`:

```
warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘int (*)(posix_spawn_file_actions_t*) noexcept’
|         std::unique_ptr<posix_spawn_file_actions_t, decltype(&posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy)>
|                                                                                                ^
```

Why is that? Should it be ignored or is there a way to adjust the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying you are ignoring the fact the function pointer doesn't throw.

Your code has other errors, like newing a pointer that isn't cleaned up by delete.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or later I use

```
template<auto x> using kval_t=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>,x>;
template<auto x> constexpr kval_t<x> kval={};
```

You can then:

```
auto action = 
  std::unique_ptr< posix_spawn_file_actions_t, kval_t<posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy> >  =
     { new posix_spawn_file_actions_t() };
```

but `new` here is probably the wrong way to create a `posix_spawn_file_actions_t`.

This stores the function pointer in a compile time constant, and may get rid of that warning.

Comment: Ok, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479567/82783 `posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy` can act on the address of a stack allocated `posix_spawn_file_actions_t`. Then I should probably get rid of the `unique_ptr` altogether, although the possibility of not reaching the call to `posix_spawn_file_actions_destroy` remains... ahw I hate when C mixes in C++

Comment: @dario you want a nullable handle like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/NullablePointer if you want to avoid a heap allocation.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I really need that. It is usual for C interfaces to provide a function that returns an allocated pointer and a second function to free it when done. I like to wrap these two in a smart pointer enforcing RAII, but I did not notice that these posix functions are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

**Yakk - Adam Nevraumont**'s answer did not work for me. In my case, I used `fclose()` in a `unique_ptr<>()` type of pointer (see [raii_generic_deleter.h](https://github.com/m2osw/snapdev/blob/main/snapdev/raii_generic_deleter.h) for details). So very similar to your code.

What I had to replace is the `decltype()`, which is rather sad, but that way the attribute warning goes away.

So I went from this declaration:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<
    FILE,
    raii_pointer_deleter<
        FILE,
        decltype(&::fclose),
        &::fclose>>     raii_file_t;
```

to that declaration:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<
    FILE,
    raii_pointer_deleter<
        FILE,
        int(*)(FILE *),   // <-- no attributes...
        &::fclose>>     raii_file_t;
```

Note that at this point I don't see the need for my code, but it looks like [it's possible to remove an attribute as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833602/remove-attribute-from-a-function-pointer-or-reference).

Comment: Is this inline with this answer using some kind of struct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867698/what-does-ignoring-attributes-on-template-argument-mean-in-this-context

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I guess the other answer shows how to "auto-remove" the attributes using the `decay_t` template. In my case, I did that manually with the risk that the `fclose()` signature could change over time.