# std::unique_ptr with custom deleter for wrapping a malloc pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, smart-pointers

I have a C library function:

```c
uint8_t* c_func();
```

This either returns a valid `uint8_t` pointer allocated with `malloc()`, or `NULL` on error. I want to wrap it in a `std::unique_ptr()` as follows:

```cpp
struct FreeDeleter {
  void operator()(void *p) const {
    std::free(p);
  }
};

template <typename T>
using unique_fptr = std::unique_ptr<T, FreeDeleter>;
```

`std::free()` does nothing if the pointer being passed to it is `NULL`, so  this should work as expected.

Is this design correct, and does it follow the best practices of wrapping a raw pointer in C++?

Comment: @JeJo lol C++ evolves so fast...`std::unique_ptr` is still considered "new" by a lot of users..

Comment: @JeJo `std::out_ptr_t`/`std::inout_ptr_t` aren't really useful here.  They're for when a function returns by out parameter (i.e. `void c_func(foo** ret)`), which doesn't apply here.  You also still have to own a `std::unique_ptr` when you use them; you just don't need an intermediate raw pointer.  Since OP's C function actually _returns_ a pointer just a `std::unique_ptr` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The code is fine. I do the same all the time including similar things for `FILE*` where the deleter calls `fclose`. For this particular case you could limit it to types that are [`std::is_trivially_destructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible) but that's just a gimmick

Comment: @Homer512 If you know it is `FILE*` why dont you just use stuff like `iostream`?

Comment: Interoperability with C libraries and the ability call [`fileno`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) or [`fdopen`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3p.html) to use POSIX routines. I also consider `fprintf` easier to read and likely faster (fewer mutex lock/unlock cycles)

Comment: @Homer512 at least try `std::format` in conjunction with `std::fputs` instead of `printf`; get some type safety in your code.

Comment: @Red.Wave Thanks but I'm targetting C++-17 at the moment. We are also getting way off-topic here.

Comment: @Homer512 last comment: C++17 is too old in various ways; Greatest miss is ranges.

Comment: @Homer512 got it. I am personally fine with this. Just I am aware that many members of the C++ community (many of them are active on SE) are very hostile towards mixing C functions with C++ lol

Comment: Speaking of mixing C and C++: I assume you have a good reason to stick with malloc and can't just switch to the array-specialization of `unique_ptr` such as `std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(number_elements)`?

Comment: Related: [std::unique_ptr for C functions that need free](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27440953/430766)

Comment: @Homer512 you might assume that the `uint8_t* c_func();` function is something given to me and I have no control over it. Just its specs say it uses `malloc()`.

Comment: Yes this code is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is best practice.

I would go one step further and wrap the C function in a function that just immediatly wraps the result in the unique_ptr, so that you can never forget to do it.

However, **big** caveat! If the C function is in a *shared library* on Windows, it might use a different heap and thus using free in your main program would be invalid. There's nothing you can do about that however unless the library provides its own custom free function, in which case you should really use that anyway.

Comment: The caveat is spot on!  I wish I could give more than +1.

Comment: As I normally dont program on Windows so I am not aware of this. Just out of curiosity, does it mean that on Windows my program canNOT `free()` the memory `malloc()`ed by a shared library function?

Comment: That's a potential issue, yes. It depends on the exact setup. In theory, if both the EXE and the DLL link dynamically to the same version of the CRT DLLs, you can malloc/free across module boundaries. But if either links statically, or to a different version, the code breaks. Because we're talking DLLs, this means it could break when the DLL is replaced without even recompiling the EXE! So it's better to just not risk it and take the relevant precautions.