# Why would I use a unique_lock<> wrapper?

Tags: c++, c++11

> Why would I use a `unique_lock<>` wrapper?

I sometimes see code like this

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_active_sessions_guard); // lock() the associated mutex
m_active_sessions[request_id] = session;
lock.unlock();
```

where a `unique_lock<>` is created just to lock the associated mutex.

Having searched, I've found that this class is not copyable. Is this the only benefit of using it?

Answer (score 2):

`unique_lock` utilizes [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) to guarantee exception-safe code. Notice that C++ [does not have a finally statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about).

In the case a exception is thrown, the mutex will still be released correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code:

```
int func()
{
    m_active_sessions_guard.lock();
    ... some code ... 
    if (x > y) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
    ... some more code ... 
    m_active_sessions_guard.unlock();
    return  1;
 }
```

We "forgot" the `unlock` in the early return when `x > y` is true. This could deadlock our program, or (worse!) cause the program to run slowly/misbehave in some other way.

By using a type that automatically unlocks the lock when the destructor is called, you are guaranteed that you don't "forget" to unlock the lock, EVER. I have certainly spent MANY hours looking for such problems, and I wouldn't wish it upon anyone - especially the ones where triggering the situation where it locks up or runs slow is only happening once in a while, so to even "catch" the failure you have to be lucky (maybe `x > y` only happens on Thursdays, in months without "r" and when the date is divisible by both 7 and 3. So if you are unlucky enough to get the bug report at the end of April, you'll be debugging for a while... :)

The basis is RAII ("Resource Allocation Is Initialization"), and it's the same logic as why you want to use `std::vector` rather than pointers and call `new`/`delete` yourself. Any time you can make the compiler do the job for you, you have a great benefit of "not having to remember". Computers programs, such as compilers, are very good at "remembering" things.