# Using RAII to replace the finally block to free memory

Tags: c++, raii

I was [studying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about) about the RAII mechanism in C++ which replaces the `finally` of Java. 
I wrote the following code to test it:

```
void foo(int* arr) {
    cout << "A" << endl;
    throw 20;
    cout << "B" << endl;
}

class Finally {
private:
    int* p;
public:
    Finally(int* arr) {
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
        p = arr;
    }

    ~Finally() {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
        delete(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int * arr = new int[10];
    new Finally(arr);
    try {
        foo(arr);
    } catch (int e) {
        cout << "Oh No!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to free the memory which I used for `arr` so I set a new class `Finally` which saves the pointer to the array and when it exits the scope it should call the destructor and free it. But the output is:

```
constructor
A
Oh No!
Done
```

No call for the destructor. It also does not work when I move the body of `main` to some other void method (like `void foo()`). What fix should I do to achieve the desired action?

Comment: C++ is not Java. You are writing C++ code as if it was Java. Naturally, it doesn't work as you expect. You also fundamentally misunderstand RAII. A proper RAII will `new` ***in the constructor*** and not somewhere else. It will also provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator as well, that does the right thing; or delete them. Finally, `new` in `main()` is completely totally wrong. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: RAII does not "replace the `finally` block in Java". Java's `finally` block is a (bad) attempt at compensating for not having deterministic destructors.

Comment: In general, `new` should be considered "advanced", only only used by people with many years of experience and only rarely even then.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the object you create with `new Finally(arr)` doesn't really gets destructed in your program.

Your allocation of the object just throws the object away immediately, leading to a memory leak, but more importantly it's created outside the scope of the try and catch.

For it to work you have to do something like

```
try {
    Finally f(arr);
    foo(arr);
} catch (int e) {
    cout << "Oh No!" << endl;
}
```

That would create a new object `f` in the try, which will then get destructed when the exception is thrown (as well as when it goes out of scope of the `try` if no exception is thrown).

Comment: Actually, `f` will be destructed whether an exception is thrown or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming C++ works liked Java.  It doesn't, so there are actually a few things wrong in your code

The statement

```
 new Finally(arr);
```

dynamically allocates a `Finally`, but it is NEVER released in your code.   Hence its destructor is never called.

Instead do

```
 Finally some_name(arr);
```

This will invoke the destructor of `Finally` - at the end of `main()` - which will give the output your expect.

However, the second thing wrong is that the destructor of `Finally` does `delete (p)` which gives undefined behaviour, since `p` is the result (in `main()`) of `new int [10]`.    To give the code well-defined behaviour, change `delete (p)` to `delete [] p`.

Third, with the two fixes above, you are not using RAII.   RAII means "Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation", which is not actually what your code does.   A better form would be to initialise `p` using a new expression in `Finally`s constructor and release it with a correct `delete` expression in the destructor.

```
class Finally
{
     private:
        int* p;
     public:
        Finally() : p(new int [10])
        {
            cout << "constructor" << endl;
        };

       ~Finally()
       {
           cout << "destructor" << endl;
           delete [] p;
       };

       int *data() {return p;};
};
```

AND replace the first two lines of your `main()` with a single line

```
Finally some_name;
```

and the call of `foo()` with

```
foo(some_name.data());
```

More generally, stop assuming that C++ works like Java.   Both languages work differently.   If you insist on using C++ constructors like you would in Java, you will write terribly buggy C++ code.