# Run common code in case of any exception occurred in c++

Tags: c++, exception

I was looking similar to `finally` for c++ but I came across [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161177/does-c-support-finally-blocks-and-whats-this-raii-i-keep-hearing-about). I have a small confusion though. If I have some common code I want to run in case of any exception,

Example:  `std::cout << "exception occured" << std::endl;`

Is there a way to do that instead of copy the same code?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool firstException = false;
    try
    {
        if(firstException)
            throw std::invalid_argument("the truth is out there!!");
        else
            throw std::domain_error("Bazzinga");
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception occured" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::domain_error const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception occured" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: All standard exceptions are derived from `std::exception`.

Comment: @molbdnilo `catch(std::exception const& e)` I have tried to add this at the end of catch list. But for the current example above, it never goes inside because for current exception there is a catch block explicitly for that. Could you please elaborate a bit how that will be helpful ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got now what ***molbdnilo*** was talking about in the comment.
The code below has the answer. :) :D

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool firstException = true;
    try
    {
        if(firstException)
            throw std::invalid_argument("the truth is out there!!");
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Bazzinga");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception occured" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "will catch any exception occured" << std::endl;
    }
}
```