# Reasons for stack unwinding fail

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I was debugging an application and encountered following code:

```
int Func()
{

 try 
 {

   CSingleLock aLock(&m_CriticalSection, TRUE);
   {
     //user code
   }
 }
 catch(...)
 {
     //exception handling
 }
 return -1;

}
```

m_CriticalSection is CCricialSection.

I found that user code throws an exception such that m_CriticalSection is not released at all. That means due to some reasons stack is corrupted and hence unwinding failed.

My question is:
1) In what different scenarios stack unwinding can fail ?

2) what different possibility of exception can be thrown such that stack unwinding fails.

3) Can I solve this problem by putting CSingleLock outside of try block ?

Thanks,

Comment: It'd help if you mentioned what sort of exception was thrown, and if it is actually caught at catch(...).

Comment: Why not put the try ... catch block around the user code instead?

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting an abnormal program termination?

I believe your `CCriticalSection` object will be released `CSingleLock`'s destructor. The destructor will get called always since this is an object on the stack. When the usercode throws, all stacks between the `throw` and the catch in your function will be unwound.

However, chances are that some other object in your user code or even the `CSingleLock` destructor has thrown another exception in the meantime. In this case the `m_CriticalSection` object will not get released properly and `std::terminate` is called and your program dies.

Here's some sample to demonstrate. Note: I am using a `std::terminate` handler function to notify me of the state. You can also use the `std::uncaught_exception` to see if there are any uncaught exceptions. There is a nice discussion and sample code on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1atwat8(VS.80).aspx).

```
struct S {
    S() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    ~S() { throw __FUNCTION__; std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;  }
};

void func() {
    try {
        S s;
        {
            throw 42;
        }
    } catch(int e) {            
         std::cout << "Exception: " << e << std::endl; 
    }
}

void rip() {
    std::cout << " help me, O mighty Lord!\n"; // pray
}

int main() {
    std::set_terminate(rip);
    try {
        func();
    }
    catch(char *se) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << se << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.3) FAQ for clarity.

> Can I solve this problem by putting CSingleLock outside of try block ?

Hard to say without having a look at the stack and error(s)/crashes. Why don't you give it a try. It may also introduce a subtle bug by hiding the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I don't know what CSingleLock and CCriticalSection do.

What I do know is that an exception thrown in your "user code" section *should* unwind the stack and destroy any variables that were created within the try { } block.

To my eyes, I would expect your aLock variable to be destroyed by an exception, but not m_CriticalSection. You are passing a pointer to m_CriticalSection to the aLock variable, but the m_CriticalSection object already exists, and was created elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

- are you sure that lifetime of your m_CriticalSection is longer that CSingleLock?
- maybe someone corrupt your stack?
- > > 3) Can I solve this problem by putting CSingleLock outside of try block ?

  in this case - yes. But remember, it is not good thing for performance to put large block in mutex.
- btw, catch(...) is not good practice in general. in Win32 it (catch(...)) catching SEH exceptions too, not only c++ exception. maybe you have core in this function and catch it with catch(...).

Comment: VC++ catch (...) has not caught SEH exceptions since VC++2005.

Comment: Good news and nice addition :)

Answer (score 0):

My question is:
1) In what different scenarios stack unwinding can fail ?

- If exit() terminate() abort() or unexpected() are called.

  - With the exception of a direct calls what situations are any of these likely to happen:
  - An unhandeled exception is thrown.  (Does not apply here)
  - [throw an exception from a destructor while another exception is popogating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor/130123#130123)

2) what different possibility of exception can be thrown such that stack unwinding fails.

- Exception thrown from constructor of throw expression
- Exception thrown from destructor while exception propogating.
- Exception thrown that is never caught (implementatin defined if this actually unwinds stack).
- Exception thrown that is not specified in exception specification.
- Exception thrown across a C ABI.
- Exception thrown inside a thread that is not caught (Implementation defined what happens)

3) Can I solve this problem by putting CSingleLock outside of try block ?

No. All of the above cause the application to terminate without further unwinding of the stack.