# What happens when i throw an exception in c++ destructor?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [throwing exceptions out of a destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor)

In C++ we should never throw an exception in the destructor . Does this code works as intended ?

```
struct a 
{ 
    ~a( ) { } 
};
struct b : public a 
{
    ~b( ) 
    { 
        throw 1; 
    }; 
};
bool c( ) 
{ 
    a* d=new b; 
    try 
    { 
        delete d; 
    } 
    catch( int e ) 
    { 
        return e; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: try to format code a little bit better, it's hard to read

Comment: I see no indication of intent. Who knows if its supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this code works as intended ?

Did you try running it yourself? Also have a look at [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.3) - according to that, yes, it will work in your simple case, but in general, you shouldn't do it. Again, it depends on how you define "work as intended" - the program will run without errors but you will possibly leak memory because the object wasn't freed.