# Is it possible to know if you're already in an exception in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

I have some code in a __destruct() method that sometimes throws an exception. The __destruct() method is being called during another exception and I'm seeing a vague error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Ignoring exception from exampleClass::__destruct() while an exception is already active
```

which is hiding the actual exception that's being called. I'd like to do something like:

```
public function __destruct() 
{
  try
  {
    // do work here
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    // check if we're already in an exception and log it
    if(already_in_exception())
    {
      error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
    // normal destruct, re-throw
    else
    {
      throw $e;
    }
  } 
}
```

Bonus points if it's PHP 5.1.6 compatible!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: It would be better to avoid throwing exceptions in destructors.  Why does your destructor need to throw an exception?  Maybe we can figure out how to avoid that.  C++ specific, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor

Comment: I don't see why an exception would prevent another handler from correctly running... It might be best to handle the exception previous to letting another occur?

Comment: I also fail to see the need to throw exceptions out of a destructor. Can you show a more concrete example?

Comment: In my particular case, the destructor is calling a PDO->rollBack(). I don't want to always log the error at that level as there are other times when I want the PDOException to bubble up to the next level.

Comment: Over simplifying quite a bit, but in general, mission critical code should not be in a destuctor.  Basically, the logic of "if this situation happens, roll back" should not be in the destructor.  Where specifically it should be depends.  The only time (well, not only... I hate absolutes) you should do anything in a desctructor that can throw an exception is if you're willing to ignore that exception (in the sense of not letting it propagate out of the dtor).

Comment: @Gary Any chance you could implement a cleanup function, manually called before destruction, that implements this functionality?

Comment: The rollback is not mission critical.. The object has a commit() function that is called when a commit is required. The default behaviour is to not commit unless requessted -- this isn't an error condition. The rollback is there to close out the pending transaction and free up any locked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't because you're throwing an exception from within another, it's because you're throwing an exception from a destructor.

From php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php I quote:

"NOTE: Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor (called in the time of script termination) causes a fatal error."

Rethink your logic abit and do this prior to deconstruction.