# Catching expection from nested function doesn't work

Tags: c++, exception

I've got a class *cnMeshHelper* whose method *cnMeshHelper::initialize*  calls various functions that may throw *cnZeroDivisionException*.
The stripped down code looks like this:

```
cnVector cnVector::getNormalized() {
    if (getLength() == 0.0) {
        #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Throwing exception in cnVector::getNormalized().\n");
        #endif // DEBUG
        throw cnZeroDivisionException();
    }
    // ...
}

cnMatrix cnMatrix::getNormalized() {
    return cnMatrix(
        T.getNormalized(),
        B.getNormalized(),
        N.getNormalized(),
        M.getNormalized() );
}

cnMatrix cnComputeTangentSpace( /* ... */ ) {
    cnMatrix mat;
    // ...
    mat.T = mat.T.getNormalized()
    return mat;
}

void cnMeshHelper::initialize(cnMesh& mesh) {
    // ...
    polygonMatrix = cnComputeTangentSpace( /* ... */ );
}

int main() {
    cnMesh* mesh = new cnMesh( /* ... */ );
    // ...
    try {
        cnMeshHelper helper;
        helper.initialize(*mesh);
    }
    catch(cnZeroDivisionException& e) {
        cout << "Zero division exceptione caught.\n";
    }
}
```

Now, in some cases, it can happen that the *cnMesh** *mesh* has invalid values that cause to throw an exception in *cnVector::getNormalized()*.
But the problem is, if this is the case, the try-catch clause does not catch the exception. The program just terminates after printing the DEBUG-text in the method above.

**Update**: Note that I can catch the exception within *cnMeshHelper::initialize()* but everything "outer" doesn't work.
Even using `catch(...)` does *not* work in the main.

Can you tell me why the exception isn't caught ?

### Got it !

It happens often, that the issue lies somewhere else. So in this case, too.
The *cnMeshHelper* destructor throwed a null-pointer because of an uninitialized member. The member was uninitialized because of the *cnZeroDivisionException* in *cnMeshHelper::initialize*.
Thanks for you help, anyway.

Comment: Executing printf in your code doesn't mean that exception is thrown. There is if operator after prinf.

Comment: Have you checked in debugger that exception is do thrown?

Comment: @AlexFarber Thanks, that was just an issue of mine when writing this question. Corrected it.

Comment: You should never allow an exception to escape a destructor. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Got it !

It happens often, that the issue lies somewhere else. So in this case, too.
The *cnMeshHelper* destructor throwed a null-pointer because of an uninitialized member. The member was uninitialized because of the **cnZeroDivisionException** in *cnMeshHelper::initialize*.
Thanks for you help, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
catch(cnZeroDivisionException& e) {
```

will catch exactly one kind of exception. But what happens if there is another exception or a non-exception abort (dereferencing NULL, ...)?

So please move the `printf` *into* the `if` sections to see if really an exception of the right type is thrown.

My crystal ball guess is that `getLength` will reveal something bad since you wrote

> ...it can happen that the cnMesh* mesh has invalid values...

These invalid values might affect `getLength` also in some way. (nullpointers, uninitialized memory, other exceptions, ...)

Comment: Sorry, I should add this to the question as well. Catching the ZeroDivisionException within the cnMeshHelper::initalize works, everything outer doesn't. I have already moved the `printf` into the if-statement, was my issue when writing the question

Answer (score 0):

Does any of the functions involved have exception specifications (`void fn() throw(some_exception)`)? They will abort the program if an exception that doesn't match the specification is thrown.

I repeat the previous advice of stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Where should I add `..() throw(some_exception) ..` ? Only the method that throws or any method that may call the throwing methods ?