# Related to Exception Handling

Tags: c++

> I am trying to call terminate function.  [I think this function gets called when another exception arises during stack unwinding]. The same scenario I have written and trying to verify.
>
> I am able to see a call being made to terminate() function but i am not sure why i am geting the Debug Error.
>
> While trying to execute the following code in Visual studio 2008, I am getting an error message dialog box "Debug Error".  The output is also being displayed:
>
> > Output:
> >
> > In try block
> >
> > In constructor of A
> >
> > In constructor of B
> >
> > In destructor of B
> >
> > In destructor of A
> >
> > Call to my_terminate
> >
> > Why this "Debug Error" window appears while executing this code?  It is expected behavior? How to remove this error?

```
class E
{
public:
      const char* message;
      E(const char* arg) : message(arg) { }
};
void my_terminate() 
{
      cout << "Call to my_terminate" << endl;
};

class A 
{
public:
      A() { cout << "In constructor of A" << endl; }
      ~A() 
      {
          cout << "In destructor of A" << endl;
          throw E("Exception thrown in ~A()");
      }
};

class B 
{
public:

         B() { cout << "In constructor of B" << endl; }
         ~B() { cout << "In destructor of B" << endl; }
};

void main() 
{
      set_terminate(my_terminate);

      try 
      {
        cout << "In try block" << endl;
        A a;
        B b;
        throw("Exception thrown in try block of main()");
      }
      catch (const char* e) 
      {
        cout << "Exception: " << e << endl;
      }
      catch (...)
      {
        cout << "Some exception caught in main()" << endl;
      }

      cout << "Resume execution of main()" << endl;
      getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing exception from `~A()`. Throwing an exception out of a destructor is dangerous. If another exception is already propagating the application will terminate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/130123/72178 for more detailed description.

> Why this "Debug Error" window appears while executing this code?

You are throwing exception in `main` from `try` block. This invokes "Stack unwinding" and destructors of `A` and `B` are called. When exception is thrown from `~A()` application terminates.

> It is expected behavior?

Yes, it is defined by Standard.

> How to remove this error?

Don't throw from destructors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure question is "why isn't that exception caught in the catch blocks?"