# Is having a function call within a destructor a good practice?

Tags: c++, destructor

Suppose there is a destructor for an object as:

```
anObject::~anObject()
{
    _functionCalledfromDestructor=1; //this sets the flag = 1
    functionCall(); //this function does something different than usual
                    //on seeing the flag
}
```

My question:

Is this style/method of coding in the destructor a good practice?

Comment: Be sure `functionCall` doesn't throw exceptions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Hidden channels" like this are always a bad idea. The behavior of a function shouldn't depend on invisible state. You could give the function an argument, and then pass one value in the destructor and another value everywhere else. You could use a default value for the more common case, if you wish.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this style/method of coding in the destructor a good practice?

If the function does two different things depending on where it's called from, then *you have two functions, not one*. Make the two functions actually be two functions and you don't need to ask this question.

Comment: It does not do entirely different things - it just write to a register different sets of bit in each of the 2 cases.

Comment: @armundle Most people would use a parameter where you've used a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no. I think you're better off doing something like this:

```
class anObject 
{
private:
  void doSomethingInternal(bool fromDestructor) {...}
public:
  void doSomething() {doSomethingInternal(false);};
  virtual ~anObject() { doSomethingInternal(true); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions inside a destructor is commonly not considered a good 
practise, as there is the possibility that an exception is thrown. This 
leads to not correctly cleaned up memory and the behaviour of exceptions
in the destructor is undefined.

Here is more information about throwing exceptions in the destructor:

[SP on throwing in the destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor)

In your case, a well defined clean up via a public interface 
is a whole better way to go. You could for example provide a `Dispose` 
method that does the clean-up.

Consider something like the following (in pseudocode):

```
public:
    void Dispose()
    {
        bool isDestructing = true;
        functionCall(isDestructing);
    }
```

Comment: Calling functions from the destructor is just fine as long as the function has the nothrow guarantee. On the other hand, requiring a cleanup to be explicitly performed before destruction is a bad practice (`std::thread` does this though), after all, this cleanup would not be called during an exception unwind.