# guarantee a certain function is called before destruction

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

while writting some C++ code i got to a point, where a certain structure needs an `end()` function call, to guarantee that the destruction is not throwing any exceptions.

`Foo a(x,y)`

`~a`  -> may throw under certain really bad circumstances

`Foo a(x,y)`

`a.end()` -> maybe throws

`~a` gurantees to not throw an exception

I wonder if there is an elegant way to force this constraint (end must be called before Deconstruction) by the compiler or at least print out a warning?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: destructor should never throws exceptions...

Comment: but wouldnt a wrapper just move the problem? The wrapper destructor would call end, but end can throw, therefore the same problem. I could use a try catch, but thats not very elegant in my opinion

Comment: the question is: who will handle this exception? If someone will, let him call it.

Comment: Actually, @OliCharlesworth's recommendation is the best approach. Ignore my previous comment..

Comment: @ChristopherSchildt: It's not common to run into situations where finalizers throw exceptions, what did you find?

Answer (score 4):

If you need stuff to occur as a prerequisite of destruction, then you should enforce that by calling it from the destructor.

But you **must** catch any exceptions, and [not let them leak from the destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor).

Comment: yes i know, i just hoped for a more elegant solution i was not aware of yet, well bad luck for me i think ;-). Thx anyway

Comment: @ChristopherSchildt: This seems like the most elegant solution; what could be more elegant than an approach that automatically invokes prerequisites at the correct time?

Comment: well i do not like the idea of a try catch within the destructor, this may be somewhat subjective, but its just looks awkward for me.