# Can I use std::current_exception during stack unwinding?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Should it be possible to use std::current_exception inside destructors of objects that are destroyed during stack unwinding?

[Documentation on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) says:

> If called during exception handling (typically, in a catch clause), captures the current exception object (...)

But it's not clear for me whether stack unwinding is a part of exception handling.

In some [highest-ranked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963673/200121) on stackoverflow author assumes that it's possible.

I did some test on my compiler (g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2) and it seems, that std::current_exception returns empty pointer in this case.

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>


struct A
{
    ~A()
    {
        std::clog << "in destructor"<<std::endl;
        std::clog << "uncaught_exception: " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
        std::clog << "current_exception: " << (bool)std::current_exception() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    try
    {
        A aa;
        std::clog << "before throw"<<std::endl;
        if(argc>1)
            throw std::runtime_error("oh no");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::clog << "in catch block"<<std::endl;
        std::clog << "uncaught_exception: " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
        std::clog << "current_exception: " << (bool)std::current_exception() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
before throw
in destructor
uncaught_exception: 1
current_exception: 0
in catch block
uncaught_exception: 0
current_exception: 1
```

Does anybody know what the standard says?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C++ Standard defines [`current_exception()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) in section § 18.8.5 [propagation] :

(emphasis mine)

> `exception_ptr current_exception() noexcept;`
>
> Returns: An exception_ptr object that refers to the currently handled
>   exception (15.3) or a copy of **the currently handled exception**, or a
>   null exception_ptr object if no exception is being handled. The
>   referenced object shall remain valid at least as long as there is an
>   exception_ptr object that refers to it.

And § 15.3 [except.handle], notes 7 and 8 :

> 7. A handler is considered **active** when initialization is complete for the
>      parameter (if any) of the catch clause. [ Note: **The stack will have
>      been unwound at that point**. — end note ]
> 8. The exception with the most recently activated **handler that is still
>      active** is called the **currently handled exception**.

The exception returned by [`current_exception()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) is defined as the "currently handled exception", which is the exception of the most recent active handler, and a handler is active only when stack unwinding completed.

---

As your tests have shown, there is no "active handler" *during* stack unwinding, so there is no "currently handled exception" either : in that case, [`current_exception()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) will return a null `exception_ptr`.

Comment: " there is no "active exception" during stack unwinding" unless an exception is being handled by a catch in or invoked from a destructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf True, I corrected the wording, please read no "active handler" (wording of the standard)

Comment: Well, it's so difficult to get right that Some™ suspect that might be the reason for `std::uncaught_exception` being unusable for any purpose. ;-)

Comment: That appears to be correct. I was surprised as well; I can see good uses for peaking at exceptions in d'tors; particularly RAII-based logging.