# How do I get the exception being thrown during unwinding?

Tags: c++

Consider the following simple example:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    public:
~Foo() {
     std::exception_ptr ptr = std::current_exception();
     if(ptr) {
        std::cout << "Stack unwinding due to exception";
     }
     std::cout << "Number of uncaught exceptions: " << std::uncaught_exceptions() << "\n";

}
};

int main() {
    try {
        Foo foo;
        throw 5;
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

With [`std::uncaught_exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) I am able to learn that there is *some* exception being thrown and not yet caught. Unfortunately [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) does not actually give the pointer to the current exception, because it only works within the `catch` clause. (also, see: [Can I use std::current_exception during stack unwinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267484/can-i-use-stdcurrent-exception-during-stack-unwinding)). So, the actual output of the above is:

```
Number of uncaught exceptions: 1
Exception caught
```

without the line `Stack unwinding due to exception`.

Is there some other way to actually get the exception pointer to the current exception being thrown? (If there are multiple, I expect to get the most recent/inner one). Maybe there is something added in the newer C++ standards?

Comment: No, there is no standard way to get it in the destructor.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili No, because that's not what I asked. I know that `std::current_exception` does not help in my case and I explained it in the question.

Comment: `std::uncaught_exceptions` is the modern option, see the post linked from the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963580/catching-exceptions-in-destructors/18963673#18963673 and https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf

Comment: @CygnusX1 If there was a way of doing it through some other standard function, you'd think people would mention that there?

Comment: Don't spam C++ versions in tags. Your question is not specific to any C++ version.

Comment: @CygnusX1, what is your goal?  Is this just a curiosity? If you had access to the exception in the destructor, what would you want to do with it?

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel I wanted to explore the possibility of alternative way of handling exceptions through RAII-like objects - something that can be passed, inherited, configured. This would allow for better separation of regular code and exceptional code. I find the try-catch block itself to be very intrusive and immobile. Currently, at best, you can have an object with a function that takes lambda as an argument and calls that lambda inside a private try-catch block. Ultimately, I do not know what the pros and cons of that approach would be as I can't experiment.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this. And more importantly, you should not *want to*.

Querying the current exception count is a mechanism that allows you to tell if your destructor (or code called by a destructor) is being invoked as part of stack unwinding or not. Such code is intended to be exception-neutral. It's not that code's job to inspect the exception and do something based on the contents of that exception.

The place where you do different things based on the exception being thrown is in the `catch` block.

It should also be noted that, even if `current_exception` did return a pointer to the current exception in flight, that wouldn't actually do what you need. Why? Because it's possible to have *multiple* exceptions unwinding the stack.

Let's say a destructor is called as the result of unwinding. That destructor code could create objects on its stack. The destructors of those stack objects *should not* consider themselves to be destroyed due to unwinding (unless the destructor itself threw an exception that caused unwinding). But since an exception is in flight, they would erroneously think that they're being called as a result of unwinding.

That's why `std::uncaught_exceptions` returns an integer, not a boolean value. It returns the number of exceptions in flight, which can be more than one (as in the above example, the destructor called as a result of unwinding could itself throw exceptions so long as it doesn't let those exceptions get emitted) The idea is that you call it in your constructor and store the value. In your destructor, you compare that to the current `std::uncaught_exceptions` value. If the new value is greater than the old, *then* you know that your destructor is being called due to unwinding.

Comment: It's a bummer that this cannot be achieved. But claiming outright that I shouldn't want that!? I believe the code could be much cleaner with it than without it (can't be sure as I can't experiment). You raise a valid concern on the possible `current_exception` behavior, but that is something that could be resolved in a similar way to the `uncaught_exceptions` pattern you describe.

Comment: @CygnusX1: Even if you only access it at the correct time, what are you going to do with the exception pointer? The only way to access the actual exception object is to throw it and re-catch it. At which point, all you've done is hidden a `catch` block inside of some object's destructor. And `catch` blocks *really* should not be hidden out-of-band like this.

Comment: Why not? I feel the answer is that no one does that and no one is accustomed to that. But if an object acts as a catcher, and its behavior is understood by the programmer, it shouldn't be a problem.