# Luabind exception not being caught when std=c++11 flag is set

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, lua, luabind

The following code snippet . . .

```
    try {
        luabind::call_function<void>(state, fName.c_str());         
    } catch (luabind::error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error calling function, \"" << fName << "\":\n";
        std::cerr << e.what() << ": " << lua_tostring(state, -1) << "\n";   
        lua_pop(state, 1);      
        assert(false);
    }
```

. . . catches runtime errors just fine when compiled as . . .

```
g++ main.cpp -llua -lluabind -ohw
```

. . . but bails out with an uncaught exception when compiled using

```
g++ main.cpp -llua -lluabind -ohw -std=c++11
```

Why?

FYI

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574323/why-cant-i-catch-a-luabinderror-exception-when-my-lua-code-throws-an-error ?

Comment: Just checked it out. Ouch. Sent a message to authors of luabind. Thanks