# luabind abort when trying to call object method with lua errors

Tags: c++, exception, lua, abort, luabind

I've used the example from http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#deriving-in-lua to define a class in c++ that I can derive from in lua:

```
class base
{
public:
    base(const char* s)
    { std::cout << s << "\n"; }

    virtual void f(int a)
    { std::cout << "f(" << a << ")\n"; }
};

struct base_wrapper : base, luabind::wrap_base
{
    base_wrapper(const char* s)
        : base(s)
    {}

    virtual void f(int a)
    {
        call<void>("f", a);
    }

    static void default_f(base* ptr, int a)
    {
        return ptr->base::f(a);
    }
};

...

module(L)
[
    class_<base, base_wrapper>("base")
        .def(constructor<const char*>())
        .def("f", &base::f, &base_wrapper::default_f)
];
```

I've then created a derived class in lua:

```
class 'base_derived' (base)

function base_derived:__init(str)
    base.__init(self,str)
end

function base_derived:f()
    this_function_doesnt_exist()
end
```

Any call to 'f' is supposed to throw a lua error, which works fine if I do it in lua:

```
local x = base_derived("Test")
x:f() -- Throws "attempt to call a nil value..." error
```

I'd like to do the equivalent of that, but in c++:

```
auto g = luabind::globals(l);
auto r = g["base_derived"];
if(r)
{
    luabind::object o = r("Test");
    auto gm = luabind::object_cast<base_wrapper*>(o);
    if(gm != nullptr)
    {
        try
        {
            luabind::call_member<void>(o,"f",5);
        }
        catch(luabind::error &e)
        {
            std::cout<<"[LUA] Error: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    o.push(l);
}
```

However the 'luabind::call_member'-call causes an abort in 'luabind/detail/call_member.hpp', line 258:

```
// Code snippet of luabind/detail/call_member.hpp
~proxy_member_void_caller()
{
    if (m_called) return;

    m_called = true;

    // don't count the function and self-reference
    // since those will be popped by pcall
    int top = lua_gettop(L) - 2;

    // pcall will pop the function and self reference
    // and all the parameters

    push_args_from_tuple<1>::apply(L, m_args);
    if (pcall(L, boost::tuples::length<Tuple>::value + 1, 0))
    {
        assert(lua_gettop(L) == top + 1);
#ifndef LUABIND_NO_EXCEPTIONS
////////////////////////////////////////////
        throw luabind::error(L); // LINE 258
////////////////////////////////////////////
#else
        error_callback_fun e = get_error_callback();
        if (e) e(L);

        assert(0 && "the lua function threw an error and exceptions are disabled."
            "If you want to handle this error use luabind::set_error_callback()");
        std::terminate();
#endif
    }
    // pops the return values from the function
    stack_pop pop(L, lua_gettop(L) - top);
}
```

The exception in that line isn't actually thrown, but it is what causes the abort.

However, the abort only happens if the lua-functions causes a lua error. If I comment the 'this_function_doesnt_exist()'-call, both the lua- and c++-versions run just fine.

Why is the 'throw luabind::error(L);' causing an abort and what can I do to safely call the function from c++ even with potential lua errors?

// Edit:
This is the call stack at the time of the abort (When 'luabind::call_member(o,"f",5);' is called):

```
>   vcruntime140d.dll!__CxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, unsigned __int64 RN, _CONTEXT * pContext, _xDISPATCHER_CONTEXT * pDC) Line 213 C++
    ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatch() Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
    vcruntime140d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 136    C++
    server.dll!luabind::detail::proxy_member_void_caller<boost::tuples::tuple<int const * __ptr64,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type> >::~proxy_member_void_caller<boost::tuples::tuple<int const * __ptr64,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type,boost::tuples::null_type> >() Line 258    C++
```

And this is the abort message:
[image]

Comment: You said you aren't getting that exception but are getting some other abort? What abort *are* you getting?

Comment: I don't quite know, the abort happens as soon as it reaches the throw-call (The assert is not causing it). I've added part of the call stack at the time of abort to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See line 254:

```
if (pcall(L, boost::tuples::length<Tuple>::value + 1, 0))
```

Here, `pcall` is asking lua to execute your `x:f(5)` equivalent call. Apparently this code returns an error because pcall() returns something different than zero. This is expected because you are *indeed* creating an error in lua by calling `this_function_doesnt_exist()`. This also explains why the abort does not happen when you comment the `this_function_doesnt_exist()` call.

Then, to the C++ code:

```
     throw luabind::error(L);
```

This error is thrown from a destructor: `~proxy_member_void_caller()`, and it turns out that [throwing an exception from a destructor is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor). This problem is known for luabind ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574323/why-cant-i-catch-a-luabinderror-exception-when-my-lua-code-throws-an-error)) to trigger the call of abort without even throwing.

The solution is to add `noexcept(false)`to the signature of `~proxy_member_void_caller()`, like this:

```
~proxy_member_void_caller() noexcept(false)
```

Comment: So annoying I keep forgetting to make this change, also you should probably set noexcept(false) on the other variants like `~proxy_member_caller()` etc