# Backwards compatible noexcept(false) for destructors

Tags: c++, destructor, noexcept

Up to C++03 destructors were generally allowed to throw arbitrary exceptions.

In C++11, however, all destructors without an explicit exception specification became `noexcept` by default.
This can be overridden with `noexcept(false)` but this code won't be accepted by pre-C++11 compilers.

One solution is to detect the need for `noexcept(false)` by checking compiler-specific `#define`s, but this still limits applicability of such code to the set of known compilers.

Is there any portable way to allow throwing arbitrary exceptions from destructors in both С++11 and C++03?

Comment: The portable way is to **not** throw exceptions from the destructor, be it C++03 or C++11. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor) for a discussion of why destructors that can throw are a bad idea. And a [GotW article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm) that also talks about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `__cplusplus` macro provided by the standard:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L                // We are using C++11 or a later version
#define NOEXCEPT_FALSE noexcept(false)
#else
#define NOEXCEPT_FALSE
#endif
```

The far better idea, however, is to simply never throw from a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rely on "compiler-specific `#define`s"...

> 16.8/1 The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:

`__cplusplus`

> The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value `201103L` when compiling a C++ translation unit.