# Throwing exception from guard class destructor causes std::terminate

Tags: c++, exception, scope

I'm trying to create a class with a "mostly-invariant" that allows clients to break the invariant if need be but only if they fix it before leaving the scope in which the nastiness happens.

Here are the two classes involved. It's similar to scope guard. More details, comments, and a small test at ideone.

http://ideone.com/dMCHVU

```
class HCAccessor;

class HasConditions
{
    // class "mostly-invariant"
    // 7 < payload_ <42
    int payload_;

    bool valid() const
    {
        if (!(7 < payload_) || !(payload_ < 42))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

public:
    HasConditions(const int payload)
        : payload_(payload)
    {
        if (!valid())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("can't construct");
        }
    }

    friend class HCAccessor;
};

class HCAccessor
{
    HasConditions& hc_;

public:
    HCAccessor(HasConditions& hc)
        : hc_(hc)
    {}

    HCAccessor(HCAccessor& other)
        : hc_(other.hc_)
    {}

    ~HCAccessor()
    {
        if (!hc_.valid())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("you broke it!");
        }
    }

    void payload(const int newval)
    {
        hc_.payload_ = newval;
    }

    int payload() const
    {
        return hc_.payload_;
    }
};
```

When the "mostly-invariant" is broken and then fixed the code seems to work. When the "mostly-invariant" remains broken and `~HCAccessor()` throws, `std::terminate` gets called and I don't know why. None of the reasons for an exception resulting in a `std::terminate` call seem to fit.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate

As far as I can tell only one exception is thrown and then immediately `std::terminate` is called.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't [throw exceptions in destructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor).

Comment: Besides throwing exceptions in destructors being bad, are you actually attempting to *catch* the exception? And how are you handling temporaries of the `HCAccessor` class? Or are you passing it by value anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destructors in C++11 are `noexcept` by default. If you really want to do this, you have to declare the destructor of HCAccessor with `noexcept(false)`:

```
~HCAccessor() noexcept(false) {
```

or an old-fashioned throw-list:

```
~HCAccessor() throw(std::runtime_error) {
```

(Kudos to Pradhan for the `noexcept(false)` syntax that I had not seen before. It's not something one needs often, I suppose).

However, **doing so is almost certainly a Bad Idea™**. Flying exceptions cause destructors to be called in stack unwinding, and if you have destructors that throw exceptions, you'll eventually find yourself trying to throw several exceptions at the same time. Which explodes.

If an instance of `HCAccessor` does not manage any resources, it has nothing to do in cleanup, and the destructor is a nop. I don't see how that is a reason to throw an exception -- just leave it be.

Comment: I had been thinking about that and if an unrelated exception is thrown and `HasConditions` is also invalid then you really do have two problems at once, it's not just an artifact of this construct. Is there *any* good way to handle that?

Comment: Not really. You'll just have to design your classes in such a way that either invalid objects cannot happen or that the destruction of an invalid object does not cause problems. The latter is not usually difficult to do. @Pradhan: Alas, that is sometimes how it goes. I'll blatantly steal the better syntax for the evil case, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

`12.4.3` of the C++11 standard says

> A declaration of a destructor that does not have an *exception-specification* is implicitly considered to have
>   the same *exception-specification* as an implicit declaration.

`15.4.14` says

> If **f** is an inheriting constructor or an implicitly declared default constructor, copy
>   constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   *exception-specification* specifies the *type-id* T if and only if T is allowed by the *exception-specification*
>   of a function directly invoked by **f**’s implicit definition; **f** allows all exceptions if any function it directly
>   invokes allows all exceptions, and **f** has the *exception-specification* *noexcept(true)* if every function it directly
>   invokes allows no exceptions.

Since the implicit destructor for `HCAccessor` would be trivial and hence `noexcept(true)` since it doesn't invoke any function, `~HCAcessor`, in the absence of an exception specification, will be declared `noexcept` as well.