# boost-python unable to catch and translate c++ exception

Tags: python, c++, exception, boost, boost-python

What reasons could there be for boost-python not to be able to catch an exception thrown in an extension module written using it's help and translate it to python? Instead, the interpreter crashes with `terminate called after throwing an instance of '<some_excpetion_class>'`.

My extension module is using some functions from *CGAL*, to which it links dynamically, and which throws the exception. It also links dynamically to the boost_python shared library. I'm on linux. It's written in `'-std=c++11'` and I prefer to compile with `clang`.

My first thought was that this is a problem of throwing exceptions accross shared library boundaries. However, I did everything I could imagine to circumvent the problem, suggesting it has nothing to do with this:

- The exception translation properly works for other exceptions thrown from my code
- I tried compiling both with clang 3.4 and gcc 4.8.2
- The code throwing is a header from CGAL, in a failing assert macro which calls info a fail function in the CGAL shared library. However, re-defining that macro such that it raises from within the extension module did not help, independent if the exception class was from CGAL or a std::exception or a boost::exception child class.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason, which had nothing to do neither with boost-python nor shared libraries:

The CGAL code is throwing from a destructor, which leads to program termination. See also: [throwing exceptions out of a destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor).