# Try Catch block in destructor

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

While reading "More Exceptional C++" by Hurb Sutter, i have stumbled upon the following code:

```
// Example 19-5: Alternative right solution
//
T::Close()
{
  // ... code that could throw ...
}

T::~T() /* throw() */
{
  try
  {
    Close();
  }
  catch( ... ) { }
}
```

My understanding was, this is not a good idea. Because, if T destructor is called during stack unwinding due to an exception, and then Close() throws an exception, then this will cause Terminate() to be called.

Can somebody shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must avoid having a destructor that may throw an exception, it's OK to catch and manage them properly.

Comment: You might care to read [N4152](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf), "uncaught exceptions", voted into C++17.

Answer (score 8):

> My understanding was, this is not a good idea. Because, if T destructor is called during stack unwinding due to an exception, and then Close() throws an exception, then this will cause Terminate() to be called.

The `try`-`catch` block is there exactly to prevent that. The code:

```
try
{
    Close();
}
catch( ... ) { }
```

will catch any exception thrown by `Close` and ignore them. Therefore the destructor **won't** throw any exception, which could lead to the termination function being called.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is whether it's OK for `Close()` to throw an exception while another exception is already active.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter if `Close` can throw unless the `catch` lets the exception escape.

Typically the `catch` clause is designed to never throw.

In fact not having the `catch` clause would introduce the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

An intersting article on catch in destructor:

https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/destructors-that-throw/

Comment: To make this a good answer, you should summarize the key points of the article that are relevant to this particular question.