# When is a exception object destroyed (and can it be controlled)?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a drop-replacement for a container, and I'm trying to 
get all the exception-guarantees in place. I'm currently writing
the `clear` method, and I want it to complete as much as possible,
and to always leave the container in a consistent state, even if
one of the destructors throw an exception. I also want to rethrow
the exception after I'm done cleaning, preferably without slicing.

This brings me to the question; when is an exception destructed?
Lets have a look at one attempt:
This is simplified for the example.

```
void container::clear()
{
    bool had_exception = false;
    std::exception* exp;
    internal_set_empty(); // this cant throw
    while( ! internal_done() )
    {
        try
        {
            internal_destruct_next(); // this might throw if T::~T() throws
        }
        catch( std::exception& e )
        {
            had_exception = true;
            exp = &e;
        }
    }
    if( had_exception )
        throw *exp;
}
```

I expect this to fail badly, because the exception is probably destructed
when it is considered handled, and this doesn't technically rethrow.

Another attempt would be taking a copy of the exception, something that
I expect would slice.

Is there a way to extend the lifetime of the exception so I can rethrow
it later?
If possible, I would also like to be able to rethrow exceptions caught
via `catch(...)` .

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr could be handy if your scenario can work.

Comment: @Mat `exception_ptr` seems like exactly what I was looking for, but it seems like there is a more fundamental problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even if one of the destructors throw an exception

Cannot be done. Destructors are nothrow for a reason- you can't recover from a throwing destructor. It's clear that you don't do anything to clean up the objects whose destructor threw- because how could you even try to do that- but that also means that you've just left them hanging around in a zombie state.

On your more specific question, you could use recursion to stay inside the catch's stack frame to try to keep deleting elements, or you could also use `std::exception_ptr` and friends in C++11 which are intended for transporting exceptions around.

Comment: Thanks. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor) to be interesting

Answer (score 1):

The current usage to pass the exception to a caller is to rethrow it in the catch bloc. Assuming you have good reasons not to do it, the only other correct way is to use a `std::exception_ptr`. With a mere `std::exception*` there are high risk that the exception is destroyed and its memory deallocated before you can throw it again.

Standard C++ 2011 draft (n4296) says at 15.1 Throwing an exception § 4 : *The exception
object is destroyed after either the last remaining active handler for the exception exits by any means other
than rethrowing, **or the last object of type std::exception_ptr that refers to the exception object is
destroyed**, whichever is later. In the former case, the destruction occurs when the handler exits, immediately
after the destruction of the object declared in the exception-declaration in the handler, if any. In the latter
case, the destruction occurs before the destructor of std::exception_ptr returns. The implementation
may then deallocate the memory for the exception object; any such deallocation is done in an unspecified
way* (emphasize mine)