# Compiler error: looser throw specifier for destuctor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, exception, legacy-code

```
#include <iostream>    

struct ICantChange
{
    virtual ~ICantChange() {}
};

struct ClassThatThrows
{
    virtual ~ClassThatThrows() noexcept(false)
    {
        throw 44;
    }
};    

struct Test : ICantChange
{
    ~Test() 
    {
    }    
    ClassThatThrows instance;
};

main()
{
    try 
    {
        Test obj;
    }
    catch(int except)
    {
        std::cout << "caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code gives error message:

```
main.cpp:20:5: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual Test::~Test() noexcept (false)’
     ~Test()
     ^
main.cpp:6:13: error:   overriding ‘virtual ICantChange::~ICantChange() noexcept’
     virtual ~ICantChange() {}
```

To fix that error the only option I see is to add `noexcept(false)` to the destructor of class `ICantChange` that I cant because it is a library class.

I know that throwing destructors are bad but now I have `Test` class and I want to catch exceptions that are thrown when it is destructed.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You can handle exception inside of destructor. Also note that you will need to rerun destructor again so object gets actually destructed.

Comment: How to do it? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that destructor or `noexcept(true)`, so by adding a member that is `noexcept(false)`, you are breaking that promise.

But don't throw in destructors: [throwing exceptions out of a destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor)

Comment: Catching exception is not the same as raising one. Just use try/catch as you would do otherwise, and as @VTT says, rerun the destructor.

Comment: But it will not not suspend the exception, right? The program will be aborted anyway?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156733/how-to-catch-exception-from-member-destructor