# Is this quote from cppreference.com about implicit throw from a destructor a typo?

Tags: c++

Does this quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block have a typo?

> Reaching the end of a catch clause for a function-try-block on a **destructor** also automatically rethrows the current exception as if by `throw;`, but a return statement is allowed.

It seems hard to believe that a destructor automatically re-throws, when every article by every expert I've ever read says that destructors should never, ever throw under any circumstance. In fact, the example code above the quote shows an implicit throw from a constructor, not a destructor.

Therefore, I wonder, is the statement wrong and should have indicated that behavior for a constructor instead?

I had been reviewing this other StackOverflow article when I started thinking about this: [C4297 warning in Visual Studio while using function-try-block (function assumed not to throw an exception but does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63176146/). It already had an answer, but nobody questioned whether the quote was accurate in the first place.

Comment: It's wrong but not like you think. Because: *warning: 'throw' will always call 'terminate', in C++11 destructors default to 'noexcept'*. At the end of the catch clause for a function-try-block on a destructor the compiler will call terminate, not throw the exception again: https://godbolt.org/z/ddTrEfa8d

Comment: Have you tried it?  You'll get a terminated program due to.implicit noexcept.  And if not, why ask before trying?  /puzzled

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont arguably correct.

Comment: Note: `return;` in the catch block will hide the exception and not throw it. It's only when it falls through.

Comment: @Yakk, at first I was puzzled by the concept of a function try block which I had never even heard of.  I didn't realize until after asking that this is different from a regular try block.  it did occur to me to experiment a bit after I asked.  I didn't experiment at first since the example code looked so strange to me that it didn't even look like valid code that I have ever seen.  I obviously stand corrected.

Comment: @shawn1874 *"very article by every expert I've ever read says that destructors should never, ever throw"* This is software design advice. The advice is : do not write a destructor that can throw because throwing destructors are hard to handle safely. It is not a language rule that destructors do not have the ability to throw, destructors are allowed to throw exceptions.

Comment: Assuming your destructor is explicitly marked `noexcept(false)`, the exception will propagate *unless* there is already an exception in-flight... in which case `std::terminate` (because can't have two exceptions in-flight concurrently).  `Foo::~Foo() noexcept(false) try { /*...*/ } catch(...) { /*oh no!*/ }`

Comment: @Francois, yes I know and I see what you are saying.  However if it's widely recommended that destructors should be designed to never throw then this language feature is going to be quite confusing and problematic for some people that would never expect an automatic rethrow to happen.  From my point of view, it is an odd expectation that I would have to manually write a return statement to prevent that from happening when writing a catch for a destructor.  I agree that we should be allowed to throw, but the language rules should require me to write it if that is what I want.

Comment: @shawn1874 It may seem surprising at first. But in practice when a function try/catch block is used with a destructor the intent will almost always be to do "something" then rethrow. It is incredibly rare that the right thing to do is to swallow an exception throw by a data member's destructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not a typo.

The cppreference article did not show an example of a destructor function try block, so I crafted one myself and tested it.  Below is the same code.  I tested with Microsoft VS2019, using the v142 platform toolset and C++20 dialect.

If you execute this, an abort will be called, which is consistent with the warning that the compiler issues.  This suggests that the function catch block does automatically re-throw, even for a destructor. If you uncomment the `return` statement, it will not throw.  Although, I find that to be counter-intuitive, writing a `return` statement provides a workaround to prevent the implicit throw, just as the referenced StackOverflow article suggests.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S
{
   std::string m;

   S(const std::string& str, int idx) try : m(str, idx)
   {
      std::cout << "S(" << str << ", " << idx << ") constructed, m = " << m << '\n';
   }
   catch (const std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "S(" << str << ", " << idx << ") failed: " << e.what() << '\n';
   } // implicit "throw;" here

   ~S() try
   {
      if (m.length() > 5) {
         throw std::exception("shouldn't have been that big!");
      }
      std::cout << "destroyed!" << std::endl;
   }
   catch (const std::exception& e)
   {
      //return;
   }
};

int main()
{
   S s1{ "ABC", 1 }; // does not throw (index is in bounds)

   try
   {
      S s2{ "ABC", 4 }; // throws (out of bounds)
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "S s2... raised an exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
   }

   try
   {
      S s3("123456", 0);
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "S s2... raised an exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
   }
}
```