# Why is my exception-in-destructor not triggering std::terminate?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I am well aware of the fact that one should not throw any exception in destructor.

But as a part of making my grip on this concept,I coded this example :-

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private: 
    int i;

public:
    A()  { i = 10;   }
    ~A() { throw 30; }
};
int main(){
    try{
        A();
        throw 10;
    }
    catch (int i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, this program should be terminated by calling std::terminate() as there will be two exceptions at the same time. But, this program is giving the following output:-

```
30
exception caught
```

Can anyone please explain me the logic behind this as to why this is not terminating?

Comment: Why `throw 10;` is expected to be executed?

Comment: Can not reproduce G++ 5.1.0: _"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'"_

Comment: It's good to know that you should not throw exception in destructor, but do you know why so ?

Comment: cannot reproduce with clang

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://ideone.com/7T91cF - terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

Comment: *I am well aware of the fact that one should not throw any exception in destructor.* => there are perfectly legitimate reasons to throw from a destructor; sometimes terminating the process is the best outcome.

Answer (score 69):

`std::terminate` will be called if an exception is thrown during **stack unwinding**. That means that if an exception is called *while another exception is being handled*, then `std::terminate` will be called.

In your example, that doesn't happen - `A();` will construct and **immediately destroy** an instance of `A`. The `throw 30` will then be caught correctly.

Changing your code to:

```
int main(){
    try{
        A a;      // begin `a` lifetime 
        throw 10; // | throw #0           
                  // | end `a` lifetime   
                  // throw #1
    }
    catch(int i){
        cout<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"exception caught"<<endl;
    }
}
```

will guarantee that `std::terminate` will be called. In this case, `a` will be destroyed and will throw **while another exception is being handled**.

[**live coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f12c8d126fda7fc)

---

Additional information:

- [cppreference/Destructors/Exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Exceptions)
- [StackOverflow: "throwing exceptions out of a destructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor)

---

Note that **in C++11 and above**, your code snippet will call `std::terminate` and provide you a warning:

> main.cpp: In destructor ‘A::~A()’:
>
> main.cpp:16:15: warning: throw will always call terminate()
>   [-Wterminate]
>
> ```
>      throw 30;
>
>            ^~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:16:15: note: **in C++11 destructors default to noexcept**
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
>
> bash: line 7:  1505 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out

As seen in the compiler output, since C++11 **destructors are implicitly `noexcept(true)`**. If you want to prevent this behavior, you can simply mark them as `noexcept(false)`. Example:

```
~A() noexcept(false)
{
    throw 30;
}
```

[**live example on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf066a2b8165a44)

Comment: Actually `std::terminate` called with unnamed variable as well. According to `iostream.h` OP uses old compiler

Comment: @Slava: that's an unrelated issue. In C++11 destructors are implicitly `noexcept`. Will amend my answer.

Answer (score 10):

In your example, `A()` construct a temporary variable for `A` then destructs it immediately. Thus `throw 10;` is never executed.

The `throw` statement taking place is in the destructor for `A`. When executing `A::~A()`, the program is not unwinding (i.e. cleaning up state from an exception) at that point. See ["Destructors that throw"](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/destructors-that-throw/) for example.