# c++ destructor throw exception by single object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand why throwing an exception from a destructor results  in a program crash.
As I found many examples of two object which throw multiple exception and compiler can't handle multiple exception  but in my case I only have a single exception thrown from the destructor. Why is my program still crashing?

```
class MyClass {
private:
    string name;
public:
    MyClass (string s) :name(s) {
        cout << "constructor " << name << endl;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        cout << "Destroying " << name << endl;
        throw "invalid";
    }
};
int main( ) 
{ 
    try {
        MyClass mainObj("M");
    }
    catch (const char *e) {
        cout << "exception: " << e << endl;
        cout << "Mission impossible!\n";
    }   
    catch (...) {
        cout << "exception: " <<  endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why not post the *complete* code? Where did you learn to remove necessary include directives etc? That's very ungood: often (though not in this case) the errors are caused by missing includes. Don't do that. Post complete code, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in Destructor C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976461/exception-in-destructor-c)

Comment: @Korni: One of the *answers* there (the currently selected "solution") answers also this question, but that *question* is different, about nested exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Explanation from the MingW g++ compiler:

```
[P:\temp]
> g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In destructor 'MyClass::~MyClass()':
foo.cpp:14:15: warning: throw will always call terminate() [-Wterminate]
         throw "invalid";
               ^~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:14:15: note: in C++11 destructors default to noexcept
```

To really let it throw you can do this:

```
~MyClass() noexcept(false){
```

Comment: Too bad MingW's error message isn't totally correct.   Throwing an exception from a destructor results in calling `terminate()` if stack unwinding is underway (i.e. if the destructor is called due to another exception being thrown and not yet caught).     If stack unwinding is not underway, throwing an exception from a destructor does not (necessarily) result in a call of `terminate()` - but it does cause other problems.

Comment: @Peter: You would be right for C++03. In C++11 and later, C++11 §15.4/9, "Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler (15.3) encounters the outermost block of a function with an exception-specification that does not allow the exception, then, — if the exception-specification is a dynamic-exception-specification, the function std::unexpected() is called (15.5.2), — otherwise, the function std::terminate() is called (15.5.1).". The current standard is C++17.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - agreed.  Although, even in C++17, someone going out of their way to throw an exception from a destructor, will probably also ensure that destructor has a throw-spec which allows that .....    (I realise that can discussion can get circular, but that's where my thinking was in the previous comment).

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 destructors are implicitly declared as `noexcept` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

> non-throwing functions are all others (those with noexcept specifier whose expression evaluates to true as well as **destructors**, defaulted special member functions, and deallocation functions)

emphasis is mine.