# Deleting objects from memory

Tags: c++

My company uses a this piece of code to delete **ALL** objects from memory.
But because of the catch(...) I wonder what happens if the destructor of that object fails (AV)? Is it ok to catch everything silently? If the destructor failed, don't we want to know about this?

```
#define DELNULL(p) \
{                  \
if (p)             \
   {               \
   try             \
      {delete p;}  \
   catch (...)     \
      {}           \
   p = NULL;       \
   }               \
}                  \
```

Comment: Do you know what `catch(...)` does?

Comment: catches everything......... silently

Comment: minimum improvement would be to use nullptr

Comment: AFAIK,. it is allowed to delete a null pointer, no need to test it.

Comment: @Max this is safe only with the standard allocator.

Comment: What version of C++ does your company use?  This code should no longer even need to be used now that we have smart pointers.  `new` and `delete` really don't have a place in modern C++ (except for placement new)

Comment: @NathanOliver - C++ Builder Tokyo (we don't use clang)

Comment: You should probably ask this on Code Review since it is 'working' code.

Comment: I'd improve it by doing:  `#define DELNULL(p) do { delete p; p = nullptr; } while(false)`

Comment: Also this is not safe: destructors should never throw to begin with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor

Comment: @freakish - Yes, definitivelly. But you used "should not" in your phrase. So, what if?

Comment: @WeGoToMars as I said: your code **does not** make it safe. Your app may still crash. See the linked answer.

Comment: @WeGoToMars and I think it will crash if for example two different destructors in inheritance chain throw. So I strongly suggest to remove this code and just enforce "noexcept" policy for destructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to catch everything silently?

It is generally not OK to silently catch everything (it's rarely OK to silently catch *anything*). It would be often useful to know about errors.

In *some* cases it may be better to not let exceptions propagate. For example, if we are in a function called from C, or if we don't want to terminate, and are in destructor or in a `noexcept` function. But, it would be better to fall back to some other form of error reporting rather than swallowing them silently.

P.S. `if (p)` check is redundant and can be safely removed.