# Avoid a call to a function that may throw in a destructor

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I have a ODBC wrapper interface that enables me to execute SQL queries in C++. In particular, I use
the [named parameter idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Parameter) for
the select statements, for example:

```
Table.Select("foo").GroupBy("bar").OrderBy("baz");
```

To achieve this effect, the class `Table_t` returns a proxy object `Select_t`:

```
class Table_t
{
// ...

public:
  Select_t Select(std::string const &Stmt)
    { return {*this, Stmt}; }

  void Execute(std::string const &Stmt);
};
```

`Select_t` combines the basic statement with the additional clauses and executes the actual statement in the destructor:

```
class Select_t
{
private:
  Table_t &Table;
  std::string  SelectStmt,
               OrderStmt,
               GroupStmt;

public:
  Select_t(Table_t &Table_, std::string const &SelectStmt) :
    Table(Table_), SelectStmt(SelectStmt_) {}

  ~Select_t()
    { /* Combine the statements */ Table.Execute(/* Combined statement */); }

  Select_t &OrderBy(std::string const &OrderStmt_)
    { OrderStmt = OrderStmt_; return *this; }

  Select_t &GroupBy(std::string const &GroupStmt_)
    { GroupStmt = GroupStmt_; return *this; }
};
```

The problem is that `Table.Execute(Stmt)` may throw and I must not throw in a destructor. Is there a
way I can work around that while retaining the named parameter idiom?

So far the only idea I came up with is to add an `Execute` function to `Select_t`, but I would prefer not to:

```
Table.Select("foo").GroupBy("bar").OrderBy("baz").Execute();
```

Comment: Inserting `try {` and `} catch(...) { }` is not an option?

Comment: Use a `try`/`catch` in the destructor, and ensure all types of exceptions are caught.   If an exception is caught, don't rethrow it (and also, obviously, don't throw another exception).   One option is the function-try-block.

Comment: You could have an extra member: `Table.Select("foo").GroupBy("bar").OrderBy("baz").Go()` and execute the statement in `Go()`. Oh You already thought of that!

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, just realised my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, separating the concerns of the query object and its execution might be a good idea.

Lazy invocation can be very useful.

The `Execute` function could reasonably be a free function.

For example:

```
auto myquery = Table.Select("foo").GroupBy("bar").OrderBy("baz");

auto future_result = marshal_to_background_thread(myquery);
//or
auto result = Execute(myquery);
```

This would lend itself to re-use with respect to prepared statements.

e.g.

```
auto myquery = Prepare(Table.Select("foo").Where(Equals("name", Param(1))).OrderBy("baz"));


auto result = Execute(myquery, {1, "bob"});
result = Execute(myquery, {1, "alice"});
```

Comment: `Execute` can even be made implicit in many cases, by implementing it as an implicit conversion from `PreparedStatement` to `Result`. (i.e. `PreparedStatement::operator Result() { return Execute(); }`.

Comment: @MSalters That's actually beautiful.

Comment: Even though I like and appreciate the idea, that would cause my code to be plagued with `Execute` calls. Part of the motivation of the wrapper was to reduce the verbosity of `SQLBindParameter`, `SQLPrepare`, `SQLExecute`, etc.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa Have a think about MSalter's idea. The execution could happen in  `operator=(Result&, Query&)`. Throwing away the result of a query is always a bad idea so the assignment could be made mandatory with `[[nodiscard]]`

Comment: I undestand but it doesn't fit very well in my current design. Now my variables are mapped to a `Table_t`, and I only have to call `Select` to "read" them, or `Insert` to insert them, or `Update`, etc. I find it very convenient, yet I have this huge issue of a potentialy throwing destructor. That's why it would be weird having to write `Execute(Table.Select("foo"))` but not `Execute(Table.Insert("foo"))` (`"foo"` in both cases is a "WHERE" clause).

Comment: What about `ResultSet result = Table.Select("foo");` - the execution can happen in the constructor of ResultSet, which means that if there's an exception, the ResultSet does not exist (by language definition)

Comment: That's similar to the Visual Basic ODBC wrapper. So maybe I must rethink my design altogether, though I liked the simmetry of `Table.Select` and `Table.Insert`. Probably, `Insert` should be `Table.Insert(ResultSet, "WHERE")`, but I would need to think how to map my C++ variables to SQL columns.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa Even an insert returns number of rows affected. It has a result (if not a result set).

Comment: I ended up using a variant of your idea. I removed the potentialy throwing instruction from the destructor. The statement is stored in the `Table_t` and when it is queried for results the select statement is executed lazily. I'm quite satisfied for this compromise solution. Thanks so much.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa great. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing "inside" a destructor is not a problem; the problem is exceptions escaping from a destructor. You need to catch the ODBC exception, and decide how to communicate the error by another interface.

Comment: I would like the exception escape the destructor and be properly handled elsewhere.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa If the destruction is caused by another exception, that would terminate your application.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry. I wan't clear enough. I want the expression `Table.Select("foo").GroupBy("bar").OrderBy("baz")` to be able to throw exceptions. My problem is that with my current design it is not.

Comment: @PilarLatiesa: What molbdnilo is saying is that if `GroupBy` throws a `std::bad_alloc` somehow, the C++ runtime destructs all temporaries including the half-done `Select_t`. Being half-done, it's reasonable to assume `Execute` fails, which gets you the second exception and a termination.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MSalters. Yes, my current design is a disaster. I assume it is impossible to rework it so that it doesn't rely on the destructor.

Comment: @Pilar I wouldn't call it a disaster. That is just a problem that can happen. A normal way to deal with this is to just catch and ignore the exception in the destructor. If a user wants to deal specially with this, they have to call `Execute` directly. That is exactly as `std::fstream` does it with `close`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor#). I think a good idea would be to set a failbit or something like that in `Table` then the user can also check in the aftermath if everything worked.