# Throwing destructor causes memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++17, smart-pointers

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class ScopeGuard final {
 public:
  explicit ScopeGuard(T callback) : callback_(std::move(callback)) {}

  ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
  ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&&) = delete;

  ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
  ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&&) = delete;

  ~ScopeGuard() noexcept(false) { callback_(); }

 private:
  T callback_;
};

static int a_instances = 0;

struct A {
  A() {
    ++a_instances;
    std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  A(A&&) = delete;
  A(const A&) = delete;
  ~A() {
    --a_instances;
    std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Res {
  std::shared_ptr<A> shared;

  explicit Res(std::shared_ptr<A> shared) : shared(shared) {
    std::cout << "res ctor" << std::endl;
  }

  Res(Res&& o) : shared(std::move(o.shared)) {
    std::cout << "res mv" << std::endl;
  }

  Res(const Res& o) : shared(o.shared) { std::cout << "res cp" << std::endl; }

  ~Res() { std::cout << "res dtor" << std::endl; }
};

Res LeakImpl() {
  ScopeGuard on_exit{[] { throw std::runtime_error("error"); }};
  Res res{std::make_shared<A>()};
  return res;
}

void Leak() {
  try {
    auto res = LeakImpl();
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  Leak();
  if (a_instances) {
    std::cout << "leak, instances count: " << a_instances << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs this (GCC 9.1, GCC 11.1 and Clang 9.0.1)

```
ctor
res ctor
error
leak, instances count: 1
```

Which means that neither `A::~A()`, nor `Res::~Res()` were called, resulting in this case in memory leak.

I suppose inside `LeakImpl()` `Res::~Res()` wasn't called before `ScopeGuard::~ScopeGuard` because of copy elision, but why wasn't it called when exception that was thrown from `ScopeGuard::~ScopeGuard` left `try` block?

If I change `LeakImpl()` like this:

```
Res LeakImpl() {
  ScopeGuard on_exit{[] { throw std::runtime_error("error"); }};
  return Res{std::make_shared<A>()};
}
```

then GCC 11.1 generated binary outputs this:

```
ctor
res ctor
res dtor
dtor
error
```

no leak

while on GCC 9.1 and Clang 9.0.1 the bug remains.

To me this looks like a bug in a compiler, what are your thoughts?

Comment: [Do not allow a destructor to emit an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130117/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson Thanks for the link! Read it. The only objective (not conceptual) argumentation I saw there for never throwing from destructors is a potential throw during stack unwinding, resulting in process termination. I intentionally posted simplified version of `ScopeGuard` to make example easier to read. In reality my `ScopeGuard` checks if stack unwinding is in progress, and if it is, it just logs exception, so it can never directly cause `std::terminate`. If you think that I missed other objective reasons why destructors should never throw please, let me know.

Comment: There is very widely held a rule of thumb that destructors must always be `nothrow`, so it is plausible that there is a compiler bug related to throwing destructors. It would be less likely to be discovered than more mainstream problems, and it may have a lower bugfix priority. As far as I can tell, there is no reason for the leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug, already reported and fixed for gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66139

I suppose, `std::shared_ptr<>` is partially created during exception throw

As a workaround, you could prevent copy elision:

```
Res LeakImpl() {
  ScopeGuard on_exit{[] { throw std::runtime_error("error"); }};
  Res res{std::make_shared<A>()};
  return std::move(res);
}
```

or create `ScopeGuard` before `Res` (destruction order is matters in this case):

```
Res LeakImpl() {
  Res res{std::make_shared<A>()};
  ScopeGuard on_exit{[] { throw std::runtime_error("error"); }};
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it. Not fixed yet though.