# [C++][ QT ] is not meant to be copied. Pass it by move instead

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I am a beginner in C++. And I don't understand this error. I just need you to explain me.

I try to show a .sqlite database in a QTableview. The problem come from:

```
model->setQuery(*qry);
```

I want to use a function called setQuery but in first argument, I set an object with *QSqlQuery type. And this error show up.

[ERROR Pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6akK.png)

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QSqlDatabase DB;
    QSqlQueryModel* model;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

    DB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    DB.setDatabaseName("Prices.sqlite");

    if (DB.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Open";

        model = new QSqlQueryModel();

        QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(DB);
        qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM Prices");
        qry->exec();

        model->setQuery(*qry);
        ui->tableView->setModel(model);

        qDebug() << "Rows: " << model->rowCount();

        DB.close();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Failed connection";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st off: That's a warning message, not an error.

Comment: 2nd: the QSqlQuery is leaking. Create it on the stack and then pass it to setQuery() via std::move()

Comment: The only thing that should be done in a destructor is freeing resources.  Qt has an elaborate (I know: also complicated) message system that can catch things closing, etc.  Check out Signals and Slots. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/if-you-shouldnt-throw-exceptions-in-a-destructor-how-do-you-handle-errors-in-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They want you to move the object behind `qry` into the function.

The shortest change would be to replace

```
model->setQuery(*qry);
```

with

```
model->setQuery(std::move(*qry));
delete qry;
```

You don't need to use new/delete in this case though. Just using automatic storage duration works:

```
    QSqlQuery qry(DB);
    qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM Prices");
    qry.exec();
    model->setQuery(std::move(qry));
```

Then you don't have to worry about forgetting to delete it.

Alternatively, since the `QSqlQuery` object is not used anywhere else, it might be best to chose the other overload for `setQuery` like this:

```
model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery("SELECT * FROM Prices", DB);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Comment: This is technically the answer to the OPs question, but I would also wrap up @Alexey answer and include a smart pointer answer.

Comment: @Alexey this answer was written at the time of Qt 6.2, your answer works fine for Qt  6.0, 6.1, and then aftwards for Qt 6.3+ .

My answer was very specifically for Qt 6.2 https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qsqlquerymodel.html

Comment: Nvm, I don't even know if Alexeys answer works for Qt 6.3 and upwards. Doesn't look like it to me. Since the deprecation of the const& version was not undone https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquerymodel-obsolete.html

Comment: @PeterT My fault about using QSqlQueryModel setQuery. Yes, it is indeed awaits rvalue and QSqlQuery should be passed using std::move. But I want to mention that instantiating an QSqlQuery object in heap is a *bad* practice and should never be used. I'll delete my answer, as yours one covers it.