Proper way of handling c++ library resource/context management
In the context of cpp-code interacting with a c libraries, I come across the following types of functions.

AcquireResource, ReleaseResource
GetList, SubmitList
open, close
Initialize, Finalize

Or in short a pair of calls, of which the first one must be called, then some work can be done, and finally the second function must be called.
Now, in the case where this is to acquire resources the RAII pattern in Cpp works quite well. The problem arises when the second call can produce an error. In this case it cannot be part of an destructor without this error being lost.
Which leads me to my question what is a good solution to this problem which ensures that if the first call is successful, then the second call will be made even if some work in between the two calls causes an exception.
Most solutions I have found online either don't garantee that the second call is made or don't allow the second call to produce an error.
To list a few "solution" I have found

RAII, doesn't allow exceptions in destructor
Template which takes a lambda, often requires the lambda to take the acquired resource / context as an argument which can lead to code of the form ( in case of multiple calls, and I haven't found a good way to deal with exceptions in this context, additionally auto can mess with some IDE disabling auto-completion or mandating fully filling in the type )

context< AcquireCall1 >( [=]( auto & r1 ){
 context< AcquireCall2 >( [=]( auto & r2 ){
   context< AcquireCall3 >( [=]( auto & r2 ){
     ...
   } );
 } );
} );


Misusing other language constructs such as a while loop, etc. which have similar issues to the template solution


If the argument types are specified and the capture list is empty, lambda can implicitly convert to function pointer; however, to force the conversion you can apply unary operator+ on the lambda.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/if-you-shouldnt-throw-exceptions-in-a-destructor-how-do-you-handle-errors-in-i

I don't see the problem, it is perfectly fine to handle (all) exceptions in destructors and there is no problem in keeping those "issues" hidden (maybe log them). With RAII I expect the problems to be at resource acquisisition not release. At least I never really had "problems" like this and I use (and rely on ) RAII since C++11 day one.

How are you planning to recover from the cleanup error? Just log it?

The destructor is the correct place. If it generates an error then handle the error in the destructor. You can throw exceptions out of the destructor (its just not a good idea). The other pattern is that used by std::fstream. The destructor calls close() (and throws away any errors), but in those situations where you do want to handle errors, the user code can manually call close. The object notes that close has already been called and does not call it in the destructor.

You can also try passing sth like "cleanup error callback" in your constructor to be executed if sth in the destructor fails. But that falls into the RAII category, just a bit more elaborate one.
